# Find file's absolute path from a list of file names in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash, file

I have a list of file names but without their absolute path. I am trying to write a script which will read the file line by line and search the files recursively in the given directory. When the file is found, it will move it to another directory. This script will run on a Linux based machine and I know how I can do it using `find` and I can eventually use `subprocess` but I was wondering if there is more Pythonic way to do it.

This is a short excerpt from the file containing the file names:

```
Florida'sUltimatePilots_Ep03.mp4
MonsterFish_2016_EP8.srt
MonsterFish_2016_EP9.srt
MonsterFish_2016_EP10.srt
Chronicles_2018_EP1.mp4
Pilot Fever 2012.mp4
```

And this is my Python script so far:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import shutil


file_list = "/home/user/test/test/files_test.txt"
input_directory = "/home/user/test/in"
output_directory = "/home/user/test/out"
srt_directory = os.path.join(output_directory, "srt")
mp4_directory = os.path.join(output_directory, "mp4")

def find_abspath(filename, input_directory):
    .......
    return filename_abspath

with open(file_list) as flist:
    for filename in flist:
        if ".mp4" in filename:
            # print(f"MP4: {filename}")
            filename_abspath = find_abspath(filename, input_directory)
            shutil.move(filename_abspath, mp4_directory)
            time.sleep(60)
        elif ".srt" in filename:
            # print(f"SRT: {filename}")
            filename_abspath = find_abspath(filename, input_directory)
            shutil.move(filename_abspath, srt_directory)
```

So I only need some help with the  `find_abspath` function. The rest I can figure out on my own. The problem is that on this machine my user doesn't have admin rights and it is not connected to the Internet, so I don't want to install any third-party libraries for Python. As a backup plan, I can try to write a `BASH` script but probably it will take me slightly more time.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at os.path.walk() I believe this function does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe this SO question can point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/how-to-use-glob-to-find-files-recursively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your exact requirement but hopefully, this might be helpful

```
def find_abspath(filename, input_directory):
    filename = filename.rstrip('\n')
    for dir_name, subdir_list, file_list in os.walk(input_directory):
        if filename in file_list:
            filename_abspath = os.path.join(dir_name, filename)
    return filename_abspath
```

Comment: Also take a look at the function os.path.abspath to normalise the absolute path

Comment: @PrateekSen it actually doesn't work, I think you need to have an additional `if` statement to check if the filename is in the `file_list` but this statement also doesn't work, so I am trying to find a way to make it work.

Comment: Apparently the `filename` and the file in the `list_files` are different even though they look exactly the same to me.

Comment: found the problem, I needed to strip the new line from the name of the file like this: `filename = filename.rstrip('\n')` And then I needed to add an if statement like this: `if filename in files:` before joining the `dir_name` and the `filename`.

Comment: I have updated the code snippet, you can check now, I hope it will work for your case.