# Find all files with an extension recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to perform some automated action on a set of XML files. I'm just learning Python so I've looked up for a similar SO answer and come up with this:

```
root_dir='/home/user/git/code'
for filename in glob.iglob(root_dir + '**/*.xml', recursive=True):
    print(filename)
```

The problem with the above code is that it finds just the top XML file which is on '/home/user/git/code' and not all those nested under that folder. The flag 'recursive' is set to true so I wonder what could be wrong with it....
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: you forgot `/` between `code` and `**` so you have `code**` instead of `code/**`
    print(filename)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2186565/9563006
btw, per @furas, just changing `root_dir + '**/*.xml'` to `root_dir + '/**/*.xml'` should solve your issue

Comment: @furas you should post that as an answer instead of a comment ;)

Comment: @exhuma when I was writing it in commend I was not sure if it resolves problem :). But I checked it now and I put it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `/` between `code` and `**` so you have `code**` instead of `code/**`

You need `/` at the end

```
 root_dir='/home/user/git/code/'
```

or at the beginning in

```
'/**/*.xml'
```

OR use `os.path.join()` instead of `+`

```
os.path.join(root_dir, '**/*.xml')
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the bug!

Answer (score 1):

I use this function endlessly for my own projects. Hope it can serve you well.

```
import os, glob

def get_files(path, extension, recursive=False):
    """
    A generator of filepaths for each file into path with the target extension.
    If recursive, it will loop over subfolders as well.
    """
    if not recursive:
        for file_path in glob.iglob(path + "/*." + extension):
            yield file_path
    else:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file_path in glob.iglob(root + "/*." + extension):
                yield file_path
```

Example: `my_desktop_pdfs = list(get_files('users/xx/Desktop','pdf'))`

In your case:

```
for f in get_files(root_dir, 'xml', recursive=True):
    print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `glob.iglob` but [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) should produce the same result:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/user/git/code'):
    for file in files:
        if (file.endswith('.xml')):
            print(file)
```

Comment: Using glob looks like a more concise version for this use-case.