# How to get a specific with glob function python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get all the arxml file in the subfolders but it is only showing the files in the respective path I gave.

```
path = r"D:\git\Master"
arxml_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "**", "*.arxml"))
```

But the `arxml_files` only contains the files of the `path` and it might have subfolders which i want to collect as well.

Comment: Can you check the syntax of your code?  path" .... "  is not valid.

Comment: I mean the path is the a random path which I have

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use glob() to find files recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/how-to-use-glob-to-find-files-recursively)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate to How to use glob() to find files recursively?

See [How to use glob() to find files recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/how-to-use-glob-to-find-files-recursively)