# How to find a folder name(not a file name) from a directory which contains(or exact match) a string(such as "Agg" or "Aggressive") in python

Tags: python-3.x, directory, string-matching

```
import os
import fnmatch
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
#basepath = 'C:\\Uni_Regensburg\\ML_I\\Classification_Algorithm\\Data\\EMG\\'
#with os.scandir(basepath) as entries:
#    for entry in entries:
#        if entry.is_file():
#            print(entry.name)

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk('C:\\University\\ML_I\\Classification_Algorithm\\Data\\EMG'):
    #print(f'found directories: {dirnames}')
    for folder in dirnames:
        #print(folder)
        for file_name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, '*.txt'):
                if (folder == 'Aggressive'):
                    print('Aggressive: ' + file_name)
```

I want to classify my data as binary classification. For this, I have to detect my two folder names: Aggressive and Normal and then I have to filter out only text files. I tried this code, but when I am running this code it returns nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use glob() to find files recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/how-to-use-glob-to-find-files-recursively)

Comment: I don't think so, I am searching for folder name and solutions in this question suggesting file name contains a string or file name ending with(fname.endwith)

Comment: `Path.rglob` allows you to search for partial matches anywhere in the path.  So, for example, you could search using a string such as `'**/Agressive/*txt'`.  E.g. `aggressive_files = [f for f in Path('.').rglob('**/Aggressive/*.txt')]`.

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/2186565/9576876

Answer (score 0):

There are some for-loops placed wrong.

```py
def find_folder(path):
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(path):
        #print(f'found directories: {dirnames}')
        for folder in dirnames:
            if 'Aggressive' in folder:
                print('Aggressive: ' + path + "\\" + folder)
                return path + "\\" + folder
```

And then you can get your files as you already did:

```py
def get_files(path_to_folder):
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(path_to_folder)
        for file_name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, '*.txt'):
                print(file_name)
```

So in the end you could call it like this

```py
fol = find_folder('C:\\University\\ML_I\\Classification_Algorithm\\Data\\EMG')
get_files(fol)
```

Comment: I used those two for loops because I want to look for the folder name and filename.

Comment: Yeah  I got something wrong but I hope it's better now.

Comment: it print only "Aggressive:Aggressive"

Comment: Which function?

Comment: find_folder() most probably.

Comment: Yes but it returns the right thing. I will change it