# Traversing through directories in python

Tags: python

I want to write a code to find all files in subdirectories respectively and then doing one operation for each subdicrectry and then as it goes on..I have came up with below codes but this travers through all files in the directory, but I need to grab all files in particular subdirectory..

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(train_path_healthy):
    for filename in files:
        if (os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, filename))[1] == ".png"):
```

Can someone help me how do that in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use glob() to find files recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/how-to-use-glob-to-find-files-recursively)

Comment: please elaborate your use case clearly which will help us to help you better. And rather than using for loop it would be  better if you  use a recursive function

Comment: `train_path_healthy` this variable has your directory defined. If you only want to get the files of a particular subdirectory you need to change this variable to your subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

One potential way is to utilize `glob` module for this and other related tasks.

**Test case:**

A folder `test` contains 3 subdirectories `1`,`2` and `3`. Each of the subdirectory contains 2 `png` and `txt` files each.

**Code:**

```
import os, glob

path = "test"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
   for name in dirs:
     print(glob.glob(root + '/' +  name + '/*.png'))
```

**Output:**

```
['test/1/2.png', 'test/1/1.png']
['test/3/4.png', 'test/3/5.png']
['test/2/4.png', 'test/2/3.png']
```