# Avoid the base path in a recursive tree walking

Tags: python, glob, os.path, pathlib

I know how to list recursively all files/folders of `d:\temp` with various methods, see [How to use glob() to find files recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/how-to-use-glob-to-find-files-recursively).
But often I'd like to avoid to have the `d:\temp\` prefix in the results, and have relative paths to this base instead.

This can be done with:

- ```
  import os, glob
  for f in glob.glob('d:\\temp\\**\\*', recursive=True):
      print(os.path.relpath(f, 'd:\\temp'))
  ```
- idem with `f.lstrip('d:\\temp\\')` which removes this prefix
- ```
  import pathlib
  root = pathlib.Path("d:\\temp")
  print([p.relative_to(root) for p in root.glob("**/*")])
  ```

These 3 solutions work. But in fact if you read the source of `glob.py`, it does accumulate/join *all* the parts of the path. So the solution above is ... "removing something that was just added before"! It works, but it's not very elegant. Idem for `pathlib` with `relative_to` which removes the prefix.

**Question: how to modify the next few lines to not have `d:\temp` in the output (without removing something that was concatenated before!)?**

```
import os

def listpath(path):
    for f in os.scandir(path):
        f2 = os.path.join(path, f)
        if os.path.isdir(f):
            yield f2
            yield from listpath(f2)
        else:
            yield f2

for f in listpath('d:\\temp'):
    print(f)

#d:\temp\New folder
#d:\temp\New folder\New Text Document - Copy.txt
#d:\temp\New folder\New Text Document.txt
#d:\temp\New Text Document - Copy.txt
#d:\temp\New Text Document.txt
```

Comment: Style tip: use rawstrings on paths to avoid all that escaping: `r'd:\temp\**\*'`. (Btw, Windows has supported forward-slash in paths since back in 1995, you can also do `r'd:/temp/**/*'`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like shown in the following example. Basically, we recursively return the path parts joining them together, but we don't join the initial root.

```
import os

def listpath(root, parent=''):
    scan = os.path.join(root, parent)
    for f in os.scandir(scan):
        f2 = os.path.join(parent, f.name)
        yield f2
        if f.is_dir():
            yield from listpath(root, f2)

for f in listpath('d:\\temp'):
    print(f)
```

In Python 3.10, which is not released yet, there will be a new [`root_dir`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/glob.html#glob.glob) option which will allow you to do this with the built-in glob with no problem:

```
import glob
glob.glob('**/*', root_dir='d:\\temp', recursive=True)
```

You could also use a 3rd party library such as the [wcmatch](https://facelessuser.github.io/wcmatch/glob/#glob) library that has already implemented this behavior (which I am the author of). But in this simple case, your `listpath` approach may be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for this great solution @facelessuser! I just edited and replaced `parent=None`, by `parent=""`, then `os.path.join` always works, no need to test if parent is None. Is it ok for you?

Comment: As a sidenote, your solution is 2x to 5x faster than the 3 unsatisfying solutions that I mentioned in the original question, great! :) (Tested with 20k files in 1k subdirs)

Comment: Yes, there is a bit more overhead compiling glob patterns and then doing actual comparisons, if all you want to do is list folders, taking that all out is much faster. Glob has its place, but if you do not need the power of matching file patterns, a simple file listing is more than sufficient.

Comment: As far as changing `parent=None` is concerned, off the top of my head, I don't see a problem, but obviously, I haven't tested it to a great extent. I'm usually pretty explicit about my conditions to avoid doing unnecessary work, but I don't see an immediate problem with always joining.