# How to use glob() to find path recursively in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.x, glob, os.walk, os.path

I have a code piece in Python 3 to find the paths recursively from a directory.

```
 >>> import glob
  >>> glob.glob('**/*.txt', recursive=True)
```

**Output in python 3**

```
 ['2.txt', 'sub/3.txt']
```

**But when I run the same code in python 2 I got this error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: glob() got an unexpected keyword argument 'recursive'
```

**Can't I use recursive option in Python 2 ? If not then what can be the possible solution in Python2.**
Please suggest :-)

Comment: did you check os.walk() ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner no. I didn't check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use glob() to find files recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/how-to-use-glob-to-find-files-recursively)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2186565/7505395 ... os.walk and  fnmatch.filter