# Script to open an App and open content inside it with Python on Linux?

Tags: python, image, jpeg, hugin

I am currently using the app hugin for some Panorama work. So lets say I have cd into a dir with a bunch on JPGS. using a script, I would like to open hugin and have the JPGs open inside it at once, without having to do that manually. I can get it to open hugin so far, but it doesn't seem to pick up the images in that dir. Please help me with this. (to clarify, I want it to pick up the JPGs just in the cd dir, I do not want it to search and levels up or below)

```py
import os 

subprocess.call("hugin")

def openFile():
 os.system("hugin " = "*.JPG")
```

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2186525/7867968)?

Comment: thanks @C.Nivs. I'm still quite new to python. so how should my code look like?