# find first file in a dir without using a loop in python

Tags: python, loops, file

I am trying to find the first result of a file found in a root directory without using a for loop.

Is that possible? I tried using rglob and os.walk() but I still end up needing a for loop to get to my result which wastes time as I only need the first result I get.

i used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/how-to-use-glob-to-find-files-recursively) post to try and use it with rglob but unfortunately it did not work for me:

```
fp = r"C:\Users\AnxPi\Desktop\test_DS"

fp_pickle = Path(fp).rglob('*test.pkl')
print(fp_pickle)
```

Output:

```
<generator object Path.rglob at 0x0000023957C84CF0>
```

It only works if I do the following, which is the same as running a for loop:

```
sorted(Path(fp).rglob(*test.pkl'))[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first value of a generator, use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next).

```
first_value = next(Path(fp).rglob('*test.pkl'))
```

If you don't want it to raise `StopIteration` if the generator is exhausted, pass in a sentinel value suitable for your use case to return instead:

```
first_value = next(Path(fp).rglob('*test.pkl'), None)
```