# pygount skip folders that start with _X recrusive

Tags: python

I read through the documentation (https://pypi.org/project/pygount/1.2.0/), but I am still confused. When running pygount in my root directory, how to I skip all folders that start with "_X" (recursive, so skip any nested folders that start with that, too).

This runs, but I don't know if it is doing what I think it is: `pygount --suffix=py --format=summary --folders-to-skip='**/_X*'`

Comment: If you think you have a solution, then consider running it in a small, controlled test environment, rather than on root. If it works there and excludes the directories you want excluded, it probably works on root as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Use `--folders-to-skip` with a list of patterns for **folder-names**, not paths.

### Example

We can't reproduce, because your question is missing an example folder structure. First let's create it with two simple Linux shell-commands (e.g. zsh, bash).

Next, we can test different arguments for the parameter [`--folders-to-skip`](https://pygount.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#cmdoption-pygount-folders-to-skip).

#### Create the sample directory structure

Create directories (2 levels deep):

```bash
$ mkdir -p pygount/src{1..3}/{A..C}
```

Then create the files, one in each directory:

```bash
$ touch pygount/src{1..3}/{A..C}/code.py
```

Now we have following structure:

```bash
$ tree pygount                                                                                                          
pygount
├── src1
│   ├── A
│   │   └── code.py
│   ├── B
│   │   └── code.py
│   └── C
│       └── code.py
├── src2
│   ├── A
│   │   └── code.py
│   ├── B
│   │   └── code.py
│   └── C
│       └── code.py
└── src3
    ├── A
    │   └── code.py
    ├── B
    │   └── code.py
    └── C
        └── code.py

12 directories, 9 files
```

#### Using pygount, without skipping

The simple way, without skipping:

```bash
$ pygount --suffix=py pygount                                                                                           0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src1/A/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src1/B/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src1/C/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src2/A/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src2/B/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src2/C/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src3/A/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src3/B/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src3/C/code.py
```

#### Issue: Just provide a single folder-name as pattern

PyGount doesn't work with *paths* for the parameter, like you may know from other Linux commands like `ls`:

```bash
$ ls **/C                                                                                                               pygount/src1/C:
code.py

pygount/src2/C:
code.py

pygount/src3/C:
code.py
```

See how a path given with `--folders-to-skip='**/C'` doesn't get matched:

```bash
$ pygount --suffix=py --folders-to-skip='**/C' pygount                                                                  0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src1/A/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src1/B/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src1/C/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src2/A/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src2/B/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src2/C/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src3/A/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src3/B/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src3/C/code.py
```

#### Using pygount with skipped folder-names

Instead the folders to skip are expected as single folder-names given as list.
See the description for related parameter [`--names-to-skip`](https://pygount.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#cmdoption-pygount-names-to-skip) in the docs:

> To specify alternative patterns, use `--folders-to-skip` and `--names-to-skip`. Both take a comma separated list of patterns, see below on the pattern syntax. To for example also prevent folders starting with two underscores (_) from being analyzed, specify `--folders-to-skip=[...],__*`.

Now skipping inner folders named `C`:

```bash
$ pygount --suffix=py --folders-to-skip='C' pygount                                                                     0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src1/A/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src1/B/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src2/A/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src2/B/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src3/A/code.py
0       __empty__       pygount pygount/src3/B/code.py
```

It skipped every folder, that has a name like `C`, even recursively. So it yields the same effect like path `**/C`.

### Concept of globs

For the different concept of filename and path patterns (*globbing*) on Unix-like systems like *glob*, *extended glob* or *globstar* (`**`) see also:

- [wildcards - bash globstar matching - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117826/bash-globstar-matching)
- [wildcards - Excluding a directory name in a zsh recursive glob - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71881/excluding-a-directory-name-in-a-zsh-recursive-glob/71884#71884)
- [bash - Recursive glob? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49913/recursive-glob)
- [How to use glob() to find files recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/how-to-use-glob-to-find-files-recursively)
- [Filename Expansion (Bash Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)
- [Bash Extended Globbing | Linux Journal](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing)
- [Globstar: New Bash Globbing Option | Linux Journal](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option)