# List Directories and get the name of the Directory

Tags: python, list, directory, operating-system

I am trying to get the code to list all the directories in a folder, change directory into that folder and get the name of the current folder. The code I have so far is below and isn't working at the minute. I seem to be getting the parent folder name.

```
import os

for directories in os.listdir(os.getcwd()): 
    dir = os.path.join('/home/user/workspace', directories)
    os.chdir(dir)
    current = os.path.dirname(dir)
    new = str(current).split("-")[0]
    print new
```

I also have other files in the folder but I do not want to list them. I have tried the below code but I haven't got it working yet either.

```
for directories in os.path.isdir(os.listdir(os.getcwd())):
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Got it working but it seems a bit round about.

```
import os
os.chdir('/home/user/workspace')
all_subdirs = [d for d in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(d)]
for dirs in all_subdirs:
    dir = os.path.join('/home/user/workspace', dirs)
    os.chdir(dir)
    current = os.getcwd()
    new = str(current).split("/")[4]
    print new
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

This will print all the subdirectories of the current directory:

```
print [name for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name)]
```

I'm not sure what you're doing with `split("-")`, but perhaps this code will help you find a solution?

If you want the full pathnames of the directories, use `abspath`:

```
print [os.path.abspath(name) for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name)]
```

Note that these pieces of code will only get the immediate subdirectories.  If you want sub-sub-directories and so on, you should use `walk` as others have suggested.

Comment: @RichieHindle -- +1 but I have already tried this. It gets me into the directories but I can't seem to get the name of each directory that I am in. It seems to give me the current path to that directory

Comment: @chrissygormley: I'm not sure what your code is doing, but to get from a full pathname to a single directory name, you can say `dirname = os.path.split(pathname)[1]`

Comment: In case of searching in a different directory: `print [name for name in os.listdir(MAIN_DIR) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(MAIN_DIR, name))]`

Answer (score 31):

**For New Versions of Python**

I liked the answer of @RichieHindle but I add a small fix for it

```
import os

folder = './my_folder'

sub_folders = [name for name in os.listdir(folder) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder, name))]

print(sub_folders)
```

otherwise it's not really work for me

Answer (score 26):

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        print os.path.join(root, name)
```

Walk is a good built-in for what you are doing

Answer (score 9):

You seem to be using Python as if it were the shell. Whenever I've needed to do something like what you're doing, I've used [os.walk()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk)

For example, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory): `[x[0] for x in os.walk(directory)]` should give you all of the subdirectories, recursively.

Answer (score 4):

Listing the entries in the current directory (`for directories in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):`) and then interpreting those entries as subdirectories of an entirely different directory (`dir = os.path.join('/home/user/workspace', directories)`) is one thing that looks fishy.

Answer (score 0):

Slight correction for python3 (same answer as @RichieHindle)

This will print all the subdirectories of the current directory in an array:

```
print( [name for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name)] )
```

To make the above simpler to read

```
for name in os.listdir("."):
    if os.path.isdir(name):
        print(name)
```

If you want the full pathnames of the directories, use abspath:

```
print( [os.path.abspath(name) for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name)])
```

Note that these pieces of code will only get the immediate subdirectories.