# Assign a variable to every directory inside one folder. (python)

Tags: python, directory

I have one folder that contains many other folders. I want to able to extract those directory names and assign them to variables. I dont know the names of those folders and I dont know the quantity either. I need just the names of those folders and not the entire path.

Example:

inside `\users\temp\` I have 2 directories. `test1`, `test2`

```
 folder[0] = test1

 folder[1] = test2
```

and so on....depending on how many directories I have.

Thank you

Comment: have a look at this looks at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120656/directory-listing-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.listdir` and a list comprehension:

```
import os
path = r"\users\temp"   #use raw string as otherwise \t will be converted to tab space
folder = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,x))]
```

Comment: thank you soooo much...I would give you a check but dont have enough points!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

print [name for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name)]
```

Or you can take reference from here
[List Directories and get the name of the Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2690368/2045676)

[os.path — Common pathname manipulations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)