# How do I list all files of a directory?

Tags: python, directory

How can I list all files of a directory in Python and add them to a `list`?

Comment: Related to [How to get a list of subdirectories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory)

Answer (score 6386):

**[`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)** returns everything inside a directory -- including both **files** and **directories**.

[**`os.path`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path)'s `isfile()` can be used to only list files:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
```

Alternatively, **[`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)** **yields two lists** for each directory it visits -- one for **files** and one for **dirs**. If you only want the top directory you can break the first time it yields:

```
from os import walk

f = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(mypath):
    f.extend(filenames)
    break
```

or, shorter:

```py
from os import walk

filenames = next(walk(mypath), (None, None, []))[2]  # [] if no file
```

Comment: To get all the full paths of the files in the sub-folders, recursively: `[os.path.join(dirpath,f) for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(mypath) for f in filenames] `

Comment: Why the need of the break?

Comment: @João Víctor Melo `os.walk()` recursively visits all subdirectories, their subdirectories, and so on. By breaking, we only visit the first directory `mypath`.

Answer (score 2562):

I prefer using the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module, as it does pattern matching and expansion.

```
import glob
print(glob.glob("/home/adam/*"))
```

It does pattern matching intuitively

```
import glob
# All files and directories ending with .txt and that don't begin with a dot:
print(glob.glob("/home/adam/*.txt")) 
# All files and directories ending with .txt with depth of 2 folders, ignoring names beginning with a dot:
print(glob.glob("/home/adam/*/*.txt"))
```

It will return a list with the queried files and directories:

```
['/home/adam/file1.txt', '/home/adam/file2.txt', .... ]
```

Note that `glob` ignores files and directories that begin with a dot `.`, as those are considered hidden files and directories, unless the pattern is something like `.*`.

Use [`glob.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.escape) to escape strings that are not meant to be patterns:

```
print(glob.glob(glob.escape(directory_name) + "/*.txt"))
```

Comment: `from glob import glob` replaces `glob.glob()` with `glob()`.

Comment: `from glob import glob as g` replaces `glob()` by `g()`.

Answer (score 1566):

list in the current directory

With `listdir` in `os` module you get the files and the folders in the current dir

```
import os

arr = os.listdir()
```

Looking in a directory

```
arr = os.listdir('c:\\files')
```

with `glob` you can specify a type of file to list like this

```
import glob

txtfiles = []
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    txtfiles.append(file)
```

or

```
mylist = [f for f in glob.glob("*.txt")]
```

get the full path of only files in the current directory

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

cwd = os.getcwd()
onlyfiles = [os.path.join(cwd, f) for f in os.listdir(cwd) if 
os.path.isfile(os.path.join(cwd, f))]
print(onlyfiles) 

['G:\\getfilesname\\getfilesname.py', 'G:\\getfilesname\\example.txt']
```

Getting the full path name with `os.path.abspath`

You get the full path in return

```
 import os
 files_path = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir()]
 print(files_path)
 
 ['F:\\documenti\applications.txt', 'F:\\documenti\collections.txt']
```

Walk: going through sub directories

os.walk returns the root, the directories list and the files list, that is why I unpacked them in r, d, f in the for loop; it, then, looks for other files and directories in the subfolders of the root and so on until there are no subfolders.

```
import os

# Getting the current work directory (cwd)
thisdir = os.getcwd()

# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(thisdir):
    for file in f:
        if file.endswith(".docx"):
            print(os.path.join(r, file))
```

To go up in the directory tree

```
# Method 1
x = os.listdir('..')

# Method 2
x= os.listdir('/')
```

Get files of a particular subdirectory with `os.listdir()`

```
import os

x = os.listdir("./content")
```

os.walk('.') - current directory

```
 import os
 arr = next(os.walk('.'))[2]
 print(arr)
 
 >>> ['5bs_Turismo1.pdf', '5bs_Turismo1.pptx', 'esperienza.txt']
```

next(os.walk('.')) and os.path.join('dir', 'file')

```
 import os
 arr = []
 for d,r,f in next(os.walk("F:\\_python")):
     for file in f:
         arr.append(os.path.join(r,file))

 for f in arr:
     print(files)

>>> F:\\_python\\dict_class.py
>>> F:\\_python\\programmi.txt
```

next... walk

```
 [os.path.join(r,file) for r,d,f in next(os.walk("F:\\_python")) for file in f]
 
 >>> ['F:\\_python\\dict_class.py', 'F:\\_python\\programmi.txt']
```

os.walk

```
x = [os.path.join(r,file) for r,d,f in os.walk("F:\\_python") for file in f]
print(x)

>>> ['F:\\_python\\dict.py', 'F:\\_python\\progr.txt', 'F:\\_python\\readl.py']
```

os.listdir() - get only txt files

```
 arr_txt = [x for x in os.listdir() if x.endswith(".txt")]
```

Using `glob` to get the full path of the files

```
from path import path
from glob import glob

x = [path(f).abspath() for f in glob("F:\\*.txt")]
```

Using `os.path.isfile` to avoid directories in the list

```
import os.path
listOfFiles = [f for f in os.listdir() if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

Using `pathlib` from Python 3.4

```
import pathlib

flist = []
for p in pathlib.Path('.').iterdir():
    if p.is_file():
        print(p)
        flist.append(p)
```

With `list comprehension`:

```
flist = [p for p in pathlib.Path('.').iterdir() if p.is_file()]
```

Use glob method in pathlib.Path()

```
import pathlib

py = pathlib.Path().glob("*.py")
```

Get all and only files with os.walk: checks only in the third element returned, i.e. the list of the files

```
import os
x = [i[2] for i in os.walk('.')]
y=[]
for t in x:
    for f in t:
        y.append(f)
```

Get only files with next in a directory: returns only the file in the root folder

```
 import os
 x = next(os.walk('F://python'))[2]
```

Get only directories with next and walk in a directory, because in the [1] element there are the folders only

```
 import os
 next(os.walk('F://python'))[1] # for the current dir use ('.')
 
 >>> ['python3','others']
```

Get all the `subdir` names with `walk`

```
for r,d,f in os.walk("F:\\_python"):
    for dirs in d:
        print(dirs)
```

`os.scandir()` from Python 3.5 and greater

```
import os
x = [f.name for f in os.scandir() if f.is_file()]

# Another example with `scandir` (a little variation from docs.python.org)
# This one is more efficient than `os.listdir`.
# In this case, it shows the files only in the current directory
# where the script is executed.

import os
with os.scandir() as i:
    for entry in i:
        if entry.is_file():
            print(entry.name)
```

Comment: Nice. I like cwd: I'd always done: `os.path.dirname(__file__)`. `os.getcwd()` is way more terse.

Answer (score 991):

```
import os
os.listdir("somedirectory")
```

will return a list of all files and directories in "somedirectory".

Comment: Why isn't this number one? Are there any drawbacks to this method? Seems by far the most simple.

Comment: it lists both directories and files.

Answer (score 195):

A one-line solution to get **only list of files** (no subdirectories):

```py
filenames = next(os.walk(path))[2]
```

or absolute pathnames:

```py
paths = [os.path.join(path, fn) for fn in next(os.walk(path))[2]]
```

Answer (score 164):

**Getting Full File Paths From a Directory and All Its Subdirectories**

```
import os

def get_filepaths(directory):
    """
    This function will generate the file names in a directory 
    tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each 
    directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), 
    it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).
    """
    file_paths = []  # List which will store all of the full filepaths.

    # Walk the tree.
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            # Join the two strings in order to form the full filepath.
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_paths.append(filepath)  # Add it to the list.

    return file_paths  # Self-explanatory.

# Run the above function and store its results in a variable.   
full_file_paths = get_filepaths("/Users/johnny/Desktop/TEST")
```

---

- The path I provided in the above function contained 3 files— two of them in the root directory, and another in a subfolder called "SUBFOLDER."  You can now do things like:
- `print full_file_paths` which will print the list:

  - `['/Users/johnny/Desktop/TEST/file1.txt', '/Users/johnny/Desktop/TEST/file2.txt', '/Users/johnny/Desktop/TEST/SUBFOLDER/file3.dat']`

If you'd like, you can open and read the contents, or focus only on files with the extension ".dat" like in the code below:

```
for f in full_file_paths:
  if f.endswith(".dat"):
    print f
```

`/Users/johnny/Desktop/TEST/SUBFOLDER/file3.dat`

Answer (score 117):

Since version 3.4 there are builtin *iterators* for this which are a lot more efficient than [`os.listdir()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir):

[`pathlib`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html): *New in version 3.4.*

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> [p for p in pathlib.Path('.').iterdir() if p.is_file()]
```

According to [PEP 428](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0428/), the aim of the [`pathlib`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library is to provide a simple hierarchy of classes to handle filesystem paths and the common operations users do over them.

[`os.scandir()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir): *New in version 3.5.*

```
>>> import os
>>> [entry for entry in os.scandir('.') if entry.is_file()]
```

Note that [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) uses [`os.scandir()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) instead of [`os.listdir()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) from version 3.5, and its speed got increased by 2-20 times according to [PEP 471](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/).

Let me also recommend reading ShadowRanger's comment below.

Comment: Note: The `os.scandir` solution is going to be more efficient than `os.listdir` with an `os.path.is_file` check or the like, even if you need a `list` (so you don't benefit from lazy iteration), because `os.scandir` uses OS provided APIs that give you the `is_file` information for free as it iterates, no per-file round trip to the disk to `stat` them at all (on Windows, the `DirEntry`s get you complete `stat` info for free, on *NIX systems it needs to `stat` for info beyond `is_file`, `is_dir`, etc., but `DirEntry` caches on first `stat` for convenience).

Answer (score 75):

### Preliminary notes

- Although there's a clear differentiation between *file* and *directory* terms in the question text, some may argue that directories are actually special files
- The statement: "*all files of a directory*" can be interpreted in two ways:

  1. All **direct** (or level 1) descendants **only**
  2. All descendants in the whole directory tree (including the ones in sub-directories)
- When the question was asked, I imagine that *Python **2***, was the *LTS* version, however the code samples will be run by *Python **3**(**.5**)* (I'll keep them as *Python 2* compliant as possible; also, any code belonging to *Python* that I'm going to post, is from ***v3.5.4*** - unless otherwise specified).
  That has consequences related to another keyword in the question: "*add them into a **list***":

  - In pre *Python 2.2* versions, sequences (iterables) were mostly represented by lists (tuples, sets, ...)
  - In *Python 2.2*, the concept of **generator** ([[Python.Wiki]: Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)) - courtesy of [[Python.Docs]: Simple statements - The yield statement](https://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement)) - was introduced. As time passed, generator counterparts started to appear for functions that returned / worked with lists
  - In *Python 3*, generator is the default behavior
  - Not sure if returning a list is still mandatory (or a generator would do as well), but passing a generator to the *list* constructor, will create a list out of it (and also consume it). The example below illustrates the differences on [[Python.Docs]: Built-in functions - map(function, iterable, *iterables)](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map)

  > ```py
  > >>> import sys
  > >>>
  > >>> sys.version
  > '2.7.10 (default, Mar  8 2016, 15:02:46) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]'
  > >>> m = map(lambda x: x, [1, 2, 3])  # Just a dummy lambda function
  > >>> m, type(m)
  > ([1, 2, 3], <type 'list'>)
  > >>> len(m)
  > 3
  > ```

  > ```py
  > >>> import sys
  > >>>
  > >>> sys.version
  > '3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'
  > >>> m = map(lambda x: x, [1, 2, 3])
  > >>> m, type(m)
  > (<map object at 0x000001B4257342B0>, <class 'map'>)
  > >>> len(m)
  > Traceback (most recent call last):
  >   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  > TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()
  > >>> lm0 = list(m)  # Build a list from the generator
  > >>> lm0, type(lm0)
  > ([1, 2, 3], <class 'list'>)
  > >>>
  > >>> lm1 = list(m)  # Build a list from the same generator
  > >>> lm1, type(lm1)  # Empty list now - generator already exhausted
  > ([], <class 'list'>)
  > ```
- The examples will be based on a directory called *root_dir* with the following structure (this example is for *Win*, but I'm using the same tree on *Nix* as well). Note that I'll be reusing the console:

  > ```bat
  > [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q003207219]> sopr.bat
  > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
  >
  > [prompt]> 
  > [prompt]> tree /f "root_dir"
  > Folder PATH listing for volume Work
  > Volume serial number is 00000029 3655:6FED
  > E:\WORK\DEV\STACKOVERFLOW\Q003207219\ROOT_DIR
  > ¦   file0
  > ¦   file1
  > ¦
  > +---dir0
  > ¦   +---dir00
  > ¦   ¦   ¦   file000
  > ¦   ¦   ¦
  > ¦   ¦   +---dir000
  > ¦   ¦           file0000
  > ¦   ¦
  > ¦   +---dir01
  > ¦   ¦       file010
  > ¦   ¦       file011
  > ¦   ¦
  > ¦   +---dir02
  > ¦       +---dir020
  > ¦           +---dir0200
  > +---dir1
  > ¦       file10
  > ¦       file11
  > ¦       file12
  > ¦
  > +---dir2
  > ¦   ¦   file20
  > ¦   ¦
  > ¦   +---dir20
  > ¦           file200
  > ¦
  > +---dir3
  > ```

### Solutions

#### Programmatic approaches

##### 1. [[Python.Docs]: os.listdir(path='.')](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir)

> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by *path*. The list is in arbitrary order, and does not include the special entries `'.'` and `'..'` ...

> ```py
> >>> import os
> >>>
> >>> root_dir = "root_dir"  # Path relative to current dir (os.getcwd())
> >>>
> >>> os.listdir(root_dir)  # List all the items in root_dir
> ['dir0', 'dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3', 'file0', 'file1']
> >>>
> >>> [item for item in os.listdir(root_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root_dir, item))]  # Filter items and only keep files (strip out directories)
> ['file0', 'file1']
> ```

A more elaborate example (*code_os_listdir.py*):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
from pprint import pformat as pf


def _get_dir_content(path, include_folders, recursive):
    entries = os.listdir(path)
    for entry in entries:
        entry_with_path = os.path.join(path, entry)
        if os.path.isdir(entry_with_path):
            if include_folders:
                yield entry_with_path
            if recursive:
                for sub_entry in _get_dir_content(entry_with_path, include_folders, recursive):
                    yield sub_entry
        else:
            yield entry_with_path


def get_dir_content(path, include_folders=True, recursive=True, prepend_folder_name=True):
    path_len = len(path) + len(os.path.sep)
    for item in _get_dir_content(path, include_folders, recursive):
        yield item if prepend_folder_name else item[path_len:]


def _get_dir_content_old(path, include_folders, recursive):
    entries = os.listdir(path)
    ret = list()
    for entry in entries:
        entry_with_path = os.path.join(path, entry)
        if os.path.isdir(entry_with_path):
            if include_folders:
                ret.append(entry_with_path)
            if recursive:
                ret.extend(_get_dir_content_old(entry_with_path, include_folders, recursive))
        else:
            ret.append(entry_with_path)
    return ret


def get_dir_content_old(path, include_folders=True, recursive=True, prepend_folder_name=True):
    path_len = len(path) + len(os.path.sep)
    return [item if prepend_folder_name else item[path_len:] for item in _get_dir_content_old(path, include_folders, recursive)]


def main(*argv):
    root_dir = "root_dir"
    ret0 = get_dir_content(root_dir, include_folders=True, recursive=True, prepend_folder_name=True)
    lret0 = list(ret0)
    print("{:} {:d}\n{:s}".format(ret0, len(lret0), pf(lret0)))
    ret1 = get_dir_content_old(root_dir, include_folders=False, recursive=True, prepend_folder_name=False)
    print("\n{:d}\n{:s}".format(len(ret1), pf(ret1)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Notes**:

- There are two implementations:

  1. One that uses generators (of course here it seems useless, since I immediately convert the result to a list)
  2. The classic one (function names ending in **_old**)
- Recursion is used (to get into subdirectories)
- For each implementation there are two functions:

  - One that starts with an *underscore* (**_**): "private" (should not be called directly) - that does all the work
  - The public one (wrapper over previous): it just strips off the initial path (if required) from the returned entries. It's an ugly implementation, but it's the only idea that I could come with at this point
- In terms of performance, generators are generally a little bit faster (considering both *creation* and  *iteration* times), but I didn't test them in recursive functions, and also I am iterating inside the function over inner generators - don't know how performance friendly is that
- Play with the arguments to get different results

**Output**:

> ```
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.05.04_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ".\code_os_listdir.py"
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> <generator object get_dir_content at 0x000002C080418F68> 22
> ['root_dir\\dir0',
>  'root_dir\\dir0\\dir00',
>  'root_dir\\dir0\\dir00\\dir000',
>  'root_dir\\dir0\\dir00\\dir000\\file0000',
>  'root_dir\\dir0\\dir00\\file000',
>  'root_dir\\dir0\\dir01',
>  'root_dir\\dir0\\dir01\\file010',
>  'root_dir\\dir0\\dir01\\file011',
>  'root_dir\\dir0\\dir02',
>  'root_dir\\dir0\\dir02\\dir020',
>  'root_dir\\dir0\\dir02\\dir020\\dir0200',
>  'root_dir\\dir1',
>  'root_dir\\dir1\\file10',
>  'root_dir\\dir1\\file11',
>  'root_dir\\dir1\\file12',
>  'root_dir\\dir2',
>  'root_dir\\dir2\\dir20',
>  'root_dir\\dir2\\dir20\\file200',
>  'root_dir\\dir2\\file20',
>  'root_dir\\dir3',
>  'root_dir\\file0',
>  'root_dir\\file1']
>
> 11
> ['dir0\\dir00\\dir000\\file0000',
>  'dir0\\dir00\\file000',
>  'dir0\\dir01\\file010',
>  'dir0\\dir01\\file011',
>  'dir1\\file10',
>  'dir1\\file11',
>  'dir1\\file12',
>  'dir2\\dir20\\file200',
>  'dir2\\file20',
>  'file0',
>  'file1']
>
> Done.
> ```

##### 2. [[Python.Docs]: os.scandir(path='.')](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.scandir)

In *Python **3.5+*** only, backport: [[PyPI]: scandir](https://pypi.org/project/scandir):

> Return an iterator of [os.DirEntry](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) objects corresponding to the entries in the directory given by *path*. The entries are yielded in arbitrary order, and the special entries `'.'` and `'..'` are not included.
>
> Using [scandir()](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.scandir) instead of [listdir()](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) can significantly increase the performance of code that also needs file type or file attribute information, because [os.DirEntry](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) objects expose this information if the operating system provides it when scanning a directory. All [os.DirEntry](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) methods may perform a system call, but [is_dir()](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.DirEntry.is_dir) and [is_file()](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.DirEntry.is_file) usually only require a system call for symbolic links; [os.DirEntry.stat()](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.DirEntry.stat) always requires a system call on Unix but only requires one for symbolic links on Windows.

> ```py
> >>> import os
> >>>
> >>> root_dir = os.path.join(".", "root_dir")  # Explicitly prepending current directory
> >>> root_dir
> '.\\root_dir'
> >>>
> >>> scandir_iterator = os.scandir(root_dir)
> >>> scandir_iterator
> <nt.ScandirIterator object at 0x00000268CF4BC140>
> >>> [item.path for item in scandir_iterator]
> ['.\\root_dir\\dir0', '.\\root_dir\\dir1', '.\\root_dir\\dir2', '.\\root_dir\\dir3', '.\\root_dir\\file0', '.\\root_dir\\file1']
> >>>
> >>> [item.path for item in scandir_iterator]  # Will yield an empty list as it was consumed by previous iteration (automatically performed by the list comprehension)
> []
> >>>
> >>> scandir_iterator = os.scandir(root_dir)  # Reinitialize the generator
> >>> for item in scandir_iterator :
> ...     if os.path.isfile(item.path):
> ...             print(item.name)
> ...
> file0
> file1
> ```

**Notes**:

- Similar to *os.listdir*
- But it's also more flexible (and offers more functionality), more *Python*ic (and in some cases, faster)

##### 3. [[Python.Docs]: os.walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk)

> Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory *top* (including *top* itself), it yields a 3-tuple (`dirpath`, `dirnames`, `filenames`).

> ```py
> >>> import os
> >>>
> >>> root_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "root_dir")  # Specify the full path
> >>> root_dir
> 'E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir'
> >>>
> >>> walk_generator = os.walk(root_dir)
> >>> root_dir_entry = next(walk_generator)  # First entry corresponds to the root dir (passed as an argument)
> >>> root_dir_entry
> ('E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir', ['dir0', 'dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3'], ['file0', 'file1'])
> >>>
> >>> root_dir_entry[1] + root_dir_entry[2]  # Display dirs and files (direct descendants) in a single list
> ['dir0', 'dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3', 'file0', 'file1']
> >>>
> >>> [os.path.join(root_dir_entry[0], item) for item in root_dir_entry[1] + root_dir_entry[2]]  # Display all the entries in the previous list by their full path
> ['E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir\\dir0', 'E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir\\dir1', 'E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir\\dir2', 'E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir\\dir3', 'E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir\\file0', 'E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir\\file1']
> >>>
> >>> for entry in walk_generator:  # Display the rest of the elements (corresponding to every subdir)
> ...     print(entry)
> ...
> ('E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir\\dir0', ['dir00', 'dir01', 'dir02'], [])
> ('E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir\\dir0\\dir00', ['dir000'], ['file000'])
> ('E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir\\dir0\\dir00\\dir000', [], ['file0000'])
> ('E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir\\dir0\\dir01', [], ['file010', 'file011'])
> ('E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir\\dir0\\dir02', ['dir020'], [])
> ('E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir\\dir0\\dir02\\dir020', ['dir0200'], [])
> ('E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir\\dir0\\dir02\\dir020\\dir0200', [], [])
> ('E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir\\dir1', [], ['file10', 'file11', 'file12'])
> ('E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir\\dir2', ['dir20'], ['file20'])
> ('E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir\\dir2\\dir20', [], ['file200'])
> ('E:\\Work\\Dev\\StackOverflow\\q003207219\\root_dir\\dir3', [], [])
> ```

**Notes**:

- Under the scenes, it uses *os.scandir* (*os.listdir* on older (*Python*) versions)
- It does the heavy lifting by recurring in subfolders

##### 4. [[Python.Docs]: glob.glob(pathname, *, root_dir=None, dir_fd=None, recursive=False, include_hidden=False)](https://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#glob.glob)

Or *glob.**i**glob*:

> Return a possibly-empty list of path names that match *pathname*, which must be a string containing a path specification. *pathname* can be either absolute (like `/usr/src/Python-1.5/Makefile`) or relative (like `../../Tools/*/*.gif`), and can contain shell-style wildcards. Broken symlinks are included in the results (as in the shell).
> ...
> ***Changed in version 3.5***: Support for recursive globs using “`**`”.

> ```py
> >>> import glob, os
> >>>
> >>> wildcard_pattern = "*"
> >>> root_dir = os.path.join("root_dir", wildcard_pattern)  # Match every file/dir name
> >>> root_dir
> 'root_dir\\*'
> >>>
> >>> glob_list = glob.glob(root_dir)
> >>> glob_list
> ['root_dir\\dir0', 'root_dir\\dir1', 'root_dir\\dir2', 'root_dir\\dir3', 'root_dir\\file0', 'root_dir\\file1']
> >>>
> >>> [item.replace("root_dir" + os.path.sep, "") for item in glob_list]  # Strip the dir name and the path separator from begining
> ['dir0', 'dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3', 'file0', 'file1']
> >>>
> >>> for entry in glob.iglob(root_dir + "*", recursive=True):
> ...     print(entry)
> ...
> root_dir\
> root_dir\dir0
> root_dir\dir0\dir00
> root_dir\dir0\dir00\dir000
> root_dir\dir0\dir00\dir000\file0000
> root_dir\dir0\dir00\file000
> root_dir\dir0\dir01
> root_dir\dir0\dir01\file010
> root_dir\dir0\dir01\file011
> root_dir\dir0\dir02
> root_dir\dir0\dir02\dir020
> root_dir\dir0\dir02\dir020\dir0200
> root_dir\dir1
> root_dir\dir1\file10
> root_dir\dir1\file11
> root_dir\dir1\file12
> root_dir\dir2
> root_dir\dir2\dir20
> root_dir\dir2\dir20\file200
> root_dir\dir2\file20
> root_dir\dir3
> root_dir\file0
> root_dir\file1
> ```

**Notes**:

- Uses *os.listdir*
- For large trees (especially if *recursive* is on), *iglob* is preferred
- Allows advanced filtering based on name (due to the wildcard)

##### 5. [[Python.Docs]: class pathlib.Path(*pathsegments)](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path)

*Python **3.4***+, backport: [[PyPI]: pathlib2](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2).

> ```py
> >>> import pathlib
> >>>
> >>> root_dir = "root_dir"
> >>> root_dir_instance = pathlib.Path(root_dir)
> >>> root_dir_instance
> WindowsPath('root_dir')
> >>> root_dir_instance.name
> 'root_dir'
> >>> root_dir_instance.is_dir()
> True
> >>>
> >>> [item.name for item in root_dir_instance.glob("*")]  # Wildcard searching for all direct descendants
> ['dir0', 'dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3', 'file0', 'file1']
> >>>
> >>> [os.path.join(item.parent.name, item.name) for item in root_dir_instance.glob("*") if not item.is_dir()]  # Display paths (including parent) for files only
> ['root_dir\\file0', 'root_dir\\file1']
> ```

**Notes**:

- This is *one* way of achieving our goal
- It's the *OOP* style of handling paths
- Offers lots of functionalities

##### 6. [[Python 2.Docs]: dircache.listdir(path)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dircache.html#dircache.listdir)

- *Python **2*** **only**
- But, according to [[GitHub]: python/cpython - (2.7) cpython/Lib/dircache.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/dircache.py), it's just a (thin) wrapper over *os.listdir* with caching

> ```py
> def listdir(path):
>     """List directory contents, using cache."""
>     try:
>         cached_mtime, list = cache[path]
>         del cache[path]
>     except KeyError:
>         cached_mtime, list = -1, []
>     mtime = os.stat(path).st_mtime
>     if mtime != cached_mtime:
>         list = os.listdir(path)
>         list.sort()
>     cache[path] = mtime, list
>     return list
> ```

##### 7. Native *OS* *API*s

*POSIX* specific:

- [[Man7]: OPENDIR(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html)
- [[Man7]: READDIR(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html)
- [[Man7]: CLOSEDIR(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/closedir.3.html)

Available via [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes):

> [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) is a foreign function library for Python. It provides C compatible data types, and allows calling functions in DLLs or shared libraries. It can be used to wrap these libraries in pure Python.

Not directly related, but check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) out before working with *CTypes*.

*code_ctypes.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ctypes as cts
import sys


DT_DIR = 4
DT_REG = 8


class NixDirent64(cts.Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ("d_ino", cts.c_ulonglong),
        ("d_off", cts.c_longlong),
        ("d_reclen", cts.c_ushort),
        ("d_type", cts.c_ubyte),
        ("d_name", cts.c_char * 256),
    )

NixDirent64Ptr = cts.POINTER(NixDirent64)


libc = this_process = cts.CDLL(None, use_errno=True)

opendir = libc.opendir
opendir.argtypes = (cts.c_char_p,)
opendir.restype = cts.c_void_p
readdir = libc.readdir
readdir.argtypes = (cts.c_void_p,)
readdir.restype = NixDirent64Ptr
closedir = libc.closedir
closedir.argtypes = (cts.c_void_p,)


def get_dir_content(path):
    ret = [path, [], []]
    pdir = opendir(cts.create_string_buffer(path.encode()))
    if not pdir:
        print("opendir returned NULL (errno: {:d})".format(cts.get_errno()))
        return ret
    cts.set_errno(0)
    while True:
        pdirent = readdir(pdir)
        if not pdirent:
            break
        dirent = pdirent.contents
        name = dirent.d_name.decode()
        if dirent.d_type & DT_DIR:
            if name not in (".", ".."):
                ret[1].append(name)
        elif dirent.d_type & DT_REG:
            ret[2].append(name)
    if cts.get_errno():
        print("readdir returned NULL (errno: {:d})".format(cts.get_errno()))
    closedir(pdir)
    return ret


def main(*argv):
    root_dir = "root_dir"
    entries = get_dir_content(root_dir)
    print("Entries:\n{:}".format(entries))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Notes**:

- It loads the three functions from *LibC* (*libc.so* - loaded in the current process) and calls them (for more details check [[SO]: How do I check whether a file exists without exceptions? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44661513/4788546) - last notes from item ***#4.***). That would place this approach very close to the *Python* / *C* edge
- *NixDirent64* is the *CTypes* representation of *struct dirent64* from [[Man7]: dirent.h(0P)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/dirent.h.0p.html) (so are the *DT_* constants) from my *Ubuntu* *OS*. On other flavors / versions, the structure definition might differ, and if so, the *CTypes* alias should be updated, otherwise it will yield ***U**ndefined **B**ehavior*
- It returns data in the *os.walk*'s format. I didn't bother to make it recursive, but starting from the existing code, that would be a fairly trivial task
- Everything is doable on *Win* as well, the data (libraries, functions, structs, constants, ...) differ

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q003207219]> python3.5 ./code_ctypes.py
> Python 3.5.10 (default, Jan 15 2022, 19:53:00) [GCC 9.3.0] 064bit on linux
>
> Entries:
> ['root_dir', ['dir0', 'dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3'], ['file0', 'file1']]
>
> Done.
> ```

##### 8. [[TimGolden]: win32file.FindFilesW](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32file__FindFilesW_meth.html)

*Win* specific:

> Retrieves a list of matching filenames, using the Windows Unicode API. An interface to the API FindFirstFileW/FindNextFileW/Find close functions.

> ```py
> >>> import os, win32file as wfile, win32con as wcon
> >>>
> >>> root_dir = "root_dir"
> >>> root_dir_wildcard = os.path.join(root_dir, "*")
> >>> entry_list = wfile.FindFilesW(root_dir_wildcard)
> >>> len(entry_list)  # Don't display the whole content as it's too long
> 8
> >>> [entry[-2] for entry in entry_list]  # Only display the entry names
> ['.', '..', 'dir0', 'dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3', 'file0', 'file1']
> >>>
> >>> [entry[-2] for entry in entry_list if entry[0] & wcon.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY and entry[-2] not in (".", "..")]  # Filter entries and only display dir names (except self and parent)
> ['dir0', 'dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3']
> >>>
> >>> [os.path.join(root_dir, entry[-2]) for entry in entry_list if entry[0] & (wcon.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | wcon.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE)]  # Only display file "full" names
> ['root_dir\\file0', 'root_dir\\file1']
> ```

**Notes**:

- *win32file.FindFilesW* is part of [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32), which is a *Python* wrapper over *WinAPI*s

##### 9. Use some (other) 3<sup>rd</sup>-party package that does the trick

Most likely, will rely on one (or more) of the above (maybe with slight customizations).

##### Notes:

- Code is meant to be portable (except places that target a specific area - which are marked) or cross:

  - *OS* (*Nix*, *Win*, )
  - *Python* version (2, 3, )
- Multiple path styles (absolute, relatives) were used across the above variants, to illustrate the fact that the "tools" used are flexible in this direction
- *os.listdir* and *os.scandir* use *opendir* / *readdir* / *closedir* ([[MS.Learn]: FindFirstFileW function (fileapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew) / [[MS.Learn]: FindNextFileW function (fileapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew) / [[MS.Learn]: FindClose function (fileapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findclose)) (via [[GitHub]: python/cpython - (main) cpython/Modules/posixmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/posixmodule.c))
- *win32file.FindFilesW* uses those (*Win* specific) functions as well (via [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - (main) pywin32/win32/src/win32file.i](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/main/win32/src/win32file.i))
- *_get_dir_content* (from point ***#1.***) can be implemented using any of these approaches (some will require more work and some less)

  - Some advanced filtering (instead of just file *vs.* *dir*) could be done: *e.g.* the *include_folders* argument could be replaced by another one (e.g. *filter_func*) which would be a function that takes a path as an argument: `filter_func=lambda x: True` (this doesn't strip out anything) and inside *_get_dir_content* something like: `if not filter_func(entry_with_path): continue` (if the function fails for one entry, it will be skipped), but the more complex the code becomes, the longer it will take to execute
- **Nota Bene!** Since recursion is used, I must mention that I did some tests on my laptop (*Win 10 pc064*), totally unrelated to this problem, and when the recursion level was reaching values somewhere in the *(990 .. 1000)* range (*recursionlimit* - 1000 (default)), I got *StackOverflow* :). If the directory tree exceeds that limit (I am not an *FS* expert, so I don't know if that is even possible), that could be a problem.
  I must also mention that I didn't try to increase *recursionlimit*, but in theory there will always be the possibility for failure, if the *dir* depth is larger than the highest possible *recursionlimit* (on that machine).
  Check [[SO]: _csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54517228/4788546) for more details on the topic
- Code samples are for demonstrative purposes only. That means that I didn't take into account error handling (I don't think there's any ***try*** / ***except*** / ***else*** / ***finally*** block), so the code is not robust (the reason is: to keep it as simple and short as possible). For production, error handling should be added as well

#### Other approaches:

##### 1. Use *Python* only as a wrapper

- Everything is done using another technology
- That technology is invoked from *Python*
- The most famous flavor that I know is what I call the *SysAdmin* approach:

  - Use *Python* (or any programming language for that matter) in order to execute *Shell* commands (and parse their outputs)
  - Some consider this a neat hack
  - I consider it more like a lame workaround (*gainarie*), as the action *per se* is performed from *Shell* (*Cmd* in this case), and thus doesn't have anything to do with *Python*
  - Filtering (*grep* / *findstr*) or output formatting could be done on both sides, but I'm not going to insist on it. Also, I deliberately used *os.system* instead of [[Python.Docs]: subprocess - Subprocess management](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) routines (*run*, *check_output*, ...)

> ```
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.05.04_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import os;os.system(\"dir /b root_dir\")"
> dir0
> dir1
> dir2
> dir3
> file0
> file1
> ```

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q003207219]> python3.5 -c "import os;os.system(\"ls root_dir\")"
> dir0  dir1  dir2  dir3  file0  file1
> ```

In general, this approach is to be avoided, since if some command output format slightly differs between *OS* versions / flavors, the parsing code should be adapted as well - not to mention differences between locales.

Answer (score 51):

I really liked [adamk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3215392/901641), suggesting that you use `glob()`, from the module of the same name. This allows you to have pattern matching with `*`s.

But as other people pointed out in the comments, `glob()` can get tripped up over inconsistent slash directions. To help with that, I suggest you use the `join()` and `expanduser()` functions in the `os.path` module, and perhaps the `getcwd()` function in the `os` module, as well.

As examples:

```
from glob import glob

# Return everything under C:\Users\admin that contains a folder called wlp.
glob('C:\Users\admin\*\wlp')
```

The above is terrible - the path has been hardcoded and will only ever work on Windows between the drive name and the `\`s being hardcoded into the path.

```
from glob    import glob
from os.path import join

# Return everything under Users, admin, that contains a folder called wlp.
glob(join('Users', 'admin', '*', 'wlp'))
```

The above works better, but it relies on the folder name `Users` which is often found on Windows and not so often found on other OSs. It also relies on the user having a specific name, `admin`.

```
from glob    import glob
from os.path import expanduser, join

# Return everything under the user directory that contains a folder called wlp.
glob(join(expanduser('~'), '*', 'wlp'))
```

This works perfectly across all platforms.

Another great example that works perfectly across platforms and does something a bit different:

```
from glob    import glob
from os      import getcwd
from os.path import join

# Return everything under the current directory that contains a folder called wlp.
glob(join(getcwd(), '*', 'wlp'))
```

Hope these examples help you see the power of a few of the functions you can find in the standard Python library modules.

Comment: Extra glob fun: starting in Python 3.5, `**` works as long as you set `recursive = True`. See the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html#glob.glob

Answer (score 42):

```
def list_files(path):
    # returns a list of names (with extension, without full path) of all files 
    # in folder path
    files = []
    for name in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, name)):
            files.append(name)
    return files
```

Answer (score 27):

If you are looking for a Python implementation of **find**, this is a recipe I use rather frequently:

```
from findtools.find_files import (find_files, Match)

# Recursively find all *.sh files in **/usr/bin**
sh_files_pattern = Match(filetype='f', name='*.sh')
found_files = find_files(path='/usr/bin', match=sh_files_pattern)

for found_file in found_files:
    print found_file
```

So I made a PyPI [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/findtools/) out of it and there is also a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ewiger/findtools). I hope that someone finds it potentially useful for this code.

Answer (score 17):

For greater results, you can use `listdir()` method of the `os` module along with a generator (a generator is a powerful iterator that keeps its state, remember?). The following code works fine with both versions: Python 2 and Python 3.

Here's a code:

```
import os

def files(path):  
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file)):
            yield file

for file in files("."):  
    print (file)
```

The `listdir()` method returns the list of entries for the given directory. The method `os.path.isfile()` returns `True` if the given entry is a file. And the `yield` operator quits the func but keeps its current state, and it returns only the name of the entry detected as a file. All the above allows us to loop over the generator function.

Answer (score 13):

**Returning a list of absolute filepaths, does not recurse into subdirectories**

```
L = [os.path.join(os.getcwd(),f) for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),f))]
```

Comment: Note: `os.path.abspath(f)` would be a somewhat cheaper substitute for `os.path.join(os.getcwd(),f)`.

Comment: I'd be more efficient still if you started with `cwd = os.path.abspath('.')`, then used `cwd` instead of `'.'` and `os.getcwd()` throughout to avoid loads of redundant system calls.

Answer (score 13):

A wise teacher told me once that:

> When there are several established ways to do something, none of them is good for all cases.

I will thus add a solution for a **subset** of the problem: quite often, we only want to check whether a file matches a start string and an end string, without going into subdirectories. We would thus like a function that returns a list of filenames, like:

```
filenames = dir_filter('foo/baz', radical='radical', extension='.txt')
```

If you care to first declare two functions, this can be done:

```
def file_filter(filename, radical='', extension=''):
    "Check if a filename matches a radical and extension"
    if not filename:
        return False
    filename = filename.strip()
    return(filename.startswith(radical) and filename.endswith(extension))

def dir_filter(dirname='', radical='', extension=''):
    "Filter filenames in directory according to radical and extension"
    if not dirname:
        dirname = '.'
    return [filename for filename in os.listdir(dirname)
                if file_filter(filename, radical, extension)]
```

This solution could be easily generalized with regular expressions (and you might want to add a `pattern` argument, if you do not want your patterns to always stick to the start or end of the filename).

Answer (score 12):

```
import os
import os.path


def get_files(target_dir):
    item_list = os.listdir(target_dir)

    file_list = list()
    for item in item_list:
        item_dir = os.path.join(target_dir,item)
        if os.path.isdir(item_dir):
            file_list += get_files(item_dir)
        else:
            file_list.append(item_dir)
    return file_list
```

Here I use a recursive structure.

Comment: The same can be achieved just in one line with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html): `filter(Path.is_file, Path().rglob('*'))`

Answer (score 9):

Using generators

```
import os
def get_files(search_path):
     for (dirpath, _, filenames) in os.walk(search_path):
         for filename in filenames:
             yield os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
list_files = get_files('.')
for filename in list_files:
    print(filename)
```

Answer (score 8):

Another very readable variant for Python 3.4+ is using pathlib.Path.glob:

```
from pathlib import Path
folder = '/foo'
[f for f in Path(folder).glob('*') if f.is_file()]
```

It is simple to make more specific, e.g. only look for Python source files which are not symbolic links, also in all subdirectories:

```
[f for f in Path(folder).glob('**/*.py') if not f.is_symlink()]
```

Answer (score 5):

For Python 2:

```
pip install rglob
```

Then do

```
import rglob
file_list = rglob.rglob("/home/base/dir/", "*")
print file_list
```

Comment: When an external dep can be avoided, do it. What is the added value of using an external dependency when all you need is already in the language?

Answer (score 4):

Here's my general-purpose function for this.  It returns a list of file paths rather than filenames since I found that to be more useful.  It has a few optional arguments that make it versatile.  For instance, I often use it with arguments like `pattern='*.txt'` or `subfolders=True`.

```
import os
import fnmatch

def list_paths(folder='.', pattern='*', case_sensitive=False, subfolders=False):
    """Return a list of the file paths matching the pattern in the specified 
    folder, optionally including files inside subfolders.
    """
    match = fnmatch.fnmatchcase if case_sensitive else fnmatch.fnmatch
    walked = os.walk(folder) if subfolders else [next(os.walk(folder))]
    return [os.path.join(root, f)
            for root, dirnames, filenames in walked
            for f in filenames if match(f, pattern)]
```

Answer (score 4):

I will provide a sample one liner where sourcepath and file type can be provided as input. The code returns a list of filenames with csv extension. Use *.* in case all files needs to be returned. This will also recursively scans the subdirectories.

`[y for x in os.walk(sourcePath) for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.csv'))]`

Modify file extensions and source path as needed.

Comment: If you are going to use `glob`, then just use `glob('**/*.csv', recursive=True)`. No need to combine this with `os.walk()` to recurse (`recursive` and `**` are supported since Python 3.5).

Answer (score 3):

*[dircache](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.7/library/dircache.html) is  "Deprecated since version 2.6: The dircache module has been removed in Python 3.0."*

```
import dircache
list = dircache.listdir(pathname)
i = 0
check = len(list[0])
temp = []
count = len(list)
while count != 0:
  if len(list[i]) != check:
     temp.append(list[i-1])
     check = len(list[i])
  else:
    i = i + 1
    count = count - 1

print temp
```