# List with all the files in directories &subdirectories with path (Python)

Tags: python

There are a lot of questions like this, and I've actually found a way to do it

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        (os.path.join(root, name))
```

But how to put all those in a single list? I want that function to return a single list with all the paths, how can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a list of all subdirectories in the current directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory)

Comment: you can simply join your 2 loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare an empty list:

```
items = []
```

and then `append` to it at the end:

```
for name in files:
    items.append(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Answer (score 1):

As a list comprehension, it is as easy as:

```
filelist = [os.path.join(root, name) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False) for name in files]
```

For lazy evaluation, you can turn it into a generator:

```
import os

filelist_gen = (os.path.join(root, name) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False) for name in files)

for i, f in enumerate(filelist_gen):
    if i >= 3:
        break
    print(f)
```

You should use this approach if you will likely not loop over the entire filelist. A list comprehension would create a list of all files before accessing even the first item.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have something like:

```
for x in y:
    some more stuff:
        foo # I have an item here!!
```

there are two approaches.

The naïve approach is to stick it all in a list immediately:

```
def all_in_a_list():
    things = []

    for x in y:
        some more stuff:
            things.append(foo) # I have an item here!!

    return things
```

A more Pythonic approach is to make a generator

```
def all_things():
    for x in y:
        some more stuff:
            yield foo # I have an item here!!
```

and turn it to a list *if need be* at the call-site:

```
list(all_things())
```