# How to get list of subdirectories names

Tags: python, list

There is a directory that contains folders as well as files of different formats.

```
import os 
my_list = os.listdir('My_directory')
```

will return full content of files and folders names. I can use, for example, `endswith('.txt')` method to select just text files names, but how to get list of just folders names?

Comment: If you use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) it gives you directories and files separately.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I usually check for directories, while assembling a list in one go. Assuming that there is a directory called `foo`, that I would like to check for sub-directories:

```
import os
output = [dI for dI in os.listdir('foo') if os.path.isdir(os.path.join('foo',dI))]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `os.walk()` in various ways

(1) to get the relative paths of subdirectories. Note that `'.'` is the same value you get from `os.getcwd()`

```
for i,j,y in os.walk('.'):
    print(i)
```

(2) to get the full paths of subdirectories

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('path'):
    print(root)
```

(3) to get a list of subdirectories folder names

```
dir_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    dir_list.extend(dirs)
print(dir_list)
```

(4) Another way is `glob` module (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36426997/7147339) answer)

Answer (score 5):

Just use `os.path.isdir` on the results returned by `os.listdir`, as in:

```
def listdirs(path):
    return [d for d in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, d))]
```

Answer (score 3):

That should work :

```
my_dirs = [d for d in os.listdir('My_directory') if os.path.isdir(os.path.join('My_directory', d))]
```

Answer (score 3):

`os.walk` already splits files and folders up into different lists, and works recursively:

```
for root,dirs,_ in os.walk('.'):
    for d in dirs:
        print os.path.join(root,d)
```