# List all folders on a NAS with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nas, synology

I am trying to list all shared folders on a **Synology NAS** with **Python**.

So let's say I want a list of every folder on *\\DISKSTATION*
**E.g.:** *public, homes, movies, etc*

Is that possible?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need just list of all folders by network path?

Comment: Running a script to list all folders by network path is only valid for the credentials the script is running under. This may or may not bring back the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `pysmb`?

```
pip install pysmb
```

To list share contents:

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

conn = SMBConnection('username', 'password', 'local_NetBIOS_name', 'remote_NetBIOS_name')
conn.connect('ip_address')
results = conn.listPath('share_name', '/optionally/some/subfolder')

for x in results:
    print x.filename
```

Will output:

```
.
..
dir1
dir2
file1
file2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

conn = SMBConnection('username', 'password', 'local_NetBIOS_name',   'remote_NetBIOS_name')
conn.connect('domain address')
folders = conn.listPath('share_name', '/relative/subfolder')

for folder in folders:
    print folder.filename
```

conn.connect can also make use of domain address like xyz.com

```
conn.connect('xyz.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

**if** you can access your NAS folder directly (without any further authentication), you may try to run python:

```
import os
os.listdir(r'\\DISKSTATION')
```

it will print out the subfolders in `\\DISKSTATION`. if you want to find all subfolders, you may follow: [Getting a list of all subdirectories in the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory)