# with os.scandir() raises AttributeError: __exit__

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror, scandir

An `AttributeError` is raised when I use the example code from python's documentation ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir)). The example code is as follows:

```
with os.scandir(path) as it:
    for entry in it:
        if not entry.name.startswith('.') and entry.is_file():
            print(entry.name)
```

The result is an `AttributeError`:

```
D:\Programming>test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    with os.scandir() as it:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Although, assigning `os.scandir()` to a variable works fine.
Could someone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The context manager support was added in **Python 3.6**, trying to use it with previous versions will raise the error you see since it isn't a context manager (and Python tries to load `__exit__` first).

[This is stated in its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) (*right under* the code snippet you saw) for `scandir`:

> *New in version 3.6: Added support for the context manager protocol* and the `close()` method. [...]

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

You can either update to Python 3.6 or, if you can't, don't use it as a context manager.

Answer (score 4):

The docs say

> New in version 3.6: Added support for the context manager protocol

You are probably running an older Python version.

Comment: That's it. I was still on 3.5.2.3.6 works perfectly, thanks!