# Folder and subfolders

Tags: python

```
for v in enumerate (["20170106", "20170113", "20170127", "20170203", "20170210", "20170224", "20170303", "20170310", "20170324", "20170331"])
    Year17 = "/Users/Name/Desktop/Datas/" + v
    csvFiles = glob.glob (os.path.join (Year17, "*.csv"))
    df = (pd.read_csv(i) for i in csvFiles)
    df = pd.concat (df, ignore_index=True)
```

The subfolders "20170106", "20170113", "20170127", etc... which are inside the folder "Year17"

This code works good, but:

- How can I avoid writing all the subfolders names "20170106", "20170113", "20170127", etc... in the *for* sentence? Maybe *os.walk*? How it would be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a list of all subdirectories in the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the pathlib library:

```
from pathlib import Path

base_path = Path("/Users/Name/Desktop/Datas/")
for v in enumerate(base_path.iterdir()):
    print(v)
```

If you only want the sub directories and not the files, add an if statement:

```
    if v[1].is_dir():
        print(v)
```