# list all directories created in os.makedirs()

Tags: python

`os.makedirs(path)` creates recursively all non existing directories

Is there a way to print all the **newly created** directories.
Say if:

```
path = '/tmp/path/to/desired/directory/a/b/c'
```

and `/tmp/path/to/desired/directory` already exists then it should return:

```
/tmp/path/to/desired/directory/a
/tmp/path/to/desired/directory/a/b
/tmp/path/to/desired/directory/a/b/c
```

Input is `/tmp/path/to/desired/directory/a/b/c` so I am not sure till what level directories are existing, so I cannot use walk. Here in this example `/tmp/path/to/desired/` may be already existing or not.

I am not looking for os.walk or list subdirectories. I am looking for only new directories created intermediately while `os.makedirs()`. The input path is NOT a static one. It can be varied so I cannot go and check list of sub directories in it or the timestamp. I need to traverse entire filesystem then

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory

Comment: Save the list before you create the directory and then compare. Or you should check the creation time. Or just wrap os.makedirs, so that you keep track of new directories.

Comment: That looks like closest possible solution as of now. Thanks @giacomo

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before performing the `makedirs` call you can check for each level of the path whether it exists or not:

```
path = '/tmp/path/to/desired/directory/a/b/c'
splitted_path = path.split('/')
subpaths = ['/'.join(splitted_path[:i]) for i in range(2,len(splitted_path)+1)]
subpaths_iter = iter(subpaths)
for subpath in subpaths_iter:
    if not os.path.exists(subpath):
        newly_created = [subpath] + list(subpaths_iter)
        os.makedirs(path)
        break
else:
    print('makedirs not needed because the path already exists')
```

The `subpaths` list is the following:

```
['/tmp', '/tmp/path', '/tmp/path/to', '/tmp/path/to/desired', '/tmp/path/to/desired/directory', '/tmp/path/to/desired/directory/a', '/tmp/path/to/desired/directory/a/b', '/tmp/path/to/desired/directory/a/b/c']
```

You may want to tweak it if you want to also check for just `/`.