# How to read one file at a time from folder and pass data as a string into API, while writing the responses back into file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, for-loop

I have a folder with 500 text files. The text files hold data that I want to send into an API. I want to write the response object from the API into another text file into a folder.

This is my code so far to loop through the files in the folder. However this loops through all the files:

```
import os

directory = os.path.normpath("file path to folder")
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            f=open(os.path.join(subdir, file),'r')
            a = f.read()
            print a
            r = requests.post(url1,data=a).content
            file = 'file path to write api response'
            f = open(file, 'a+')
            f.write(r)
            f.close()
```

How do I only loop through one file at a time and pass the result into the api?

Comment: check this out, it may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50721824/6798902

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `glob` for iterating over the *.txt files.

```
Import glob
f = “./path/to/file/*.txt”
for files in glob.glob(f)
    with open(files) as f:
        #do your code here
```