# Query and list all available directories of the computer I'm using

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I tried a python code to search all directories inside a main folder in my pc, the code is:

```
[x[0] for x in os.walk(dir)]
```

that I found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory).

Well, now I'm interested in writing a similar code able to search and list all available directories in my pc without specifying the main directory 'dir' (suppose I don't know if I'm in C:\, in E:\, in C:\python2.7\, etc...). For 'available' I mean all directories that can be opened/read/modified and are accessible with my account (which has specific privileges that, suppose, I do not know).

Have you some working codes to perform what I ask?

Thank you

Comment: You tagged your question with both [python-3.x] and [python-2.7]; which one is it?

Comment: You are right, sorry, I'm using mainly Python 2.7, can you suggest me a py2.7 solution, thanks

Comment: I did, see the edit on my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Python 3, you have access to `pathlib.Path`

You have to start at *some* directory, for example your current working directory. From that, you can get the root of the file system (`/` under *n*x, `letter:\` under Windows):

```
import os
import pathlib

root = str(pathlib.Path(os.getcwd()).absolute().root)

all_dirs = [x[0] for x in os.walk(root)]
```

---

In Python 2.7 on Windows, you can use `os.path.splitdrive` to split `os.getcwd()` into drive letter and path and go from there.

```
import os

root, path = os.path.splitdrive(os.getcwd())
all_dirs = [x[0] for x in os.walk(root + "/")]
```

Note that I use `/` instead of `\`: Windows supports the use of a forward slash as well, and like this it will also work on other systems (because `root` will be an empty string there).

Comment: Hi, thank you, your codes works very well. Sorry, could you suggest me also a Linux version of the code for both python versions (2.7 and 3.x)?

Comment: @MatteoVR They both work under Linux — that's where I tested them.

Comment: Ok @L3viathan, thank you very much, I will try them in my linux virtual machine. Bye

Comment: Your codes works very well also in Linux I use! Thanks again