# Program to print all folder and subfolder names in specific folder

Tags: python, printing, directory, subdirectory, names

I should do it wiht only import os

I have problem, that i don't know how to make program after checking the specific folder for folders to do the same for folders in these folders and so on.

Comment: Look at this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/973488/12613186](https://stackoverflow.com/a/973488/12613186)

Comment: What specifically is your problem? If you are trying to get your script to print out the file structure of the directory it is in, this may help: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way is using `os.walk` like this:

```py
import os
path = '.'
folder_paths = [
    paths[0] for paths in os.walk(path)
]

print(folder_paths)
```

If you need a custom recursive function you can use `os.listdir` and `os.path.isdir` instead:

```py
def print_sub_dirs(path):
    folder_paths = [
        os.path.join(path, folder) for folder in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, folder))
    ]
    for folder_path in folder_paths:
        print(folder_path)
        print_sub_dirs(folder_path)

print_sub_dirs('.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.walk(directory)`