# How to get list of subdirectories?

Tags: python, directory, path, operating-system, pathlib

I have such structure of folders:

```
some_directory/subdir1/subdir1_1
some_directory/subdir1/subdir1_2
some_directory/subdir2/subdir2_1
etc.
```

My code below returns me : `['subdir1', subdir2]`

**Code:**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

IMG_IN_PATH = Path('some_directory')
DIR_LIST = sorted([f.name for f in list(IMG_IN_PATH.glob('*/'))])
print(DIR_LIST)
```

I need to get such list: `['subdir1/subdir1_1',  'subdir1/subdir1_2',  'subdir2/subdir2_1']`.

How to realize it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a list of all subdirectories in the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory)

Comment: Also see `os.listdir` for examining a single directory.

Comment: What are you trying to find ? All images inside directories ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use parts for getting the subdirectory names.

```
from pathlib import Path

IMG_IN_PATH = Path('some_directory')
DIR_LIST = sorted([str(Path(f.parts[-2]) / f.parts[-1]) for f in list(IMG_IN_PATH.glob('*/*'))])
print(DIR_LIST)
```