# How to get the names of the Subfolders that exist under the main folder using python?

Tags: python-3.x

Example: I have the main folder named "alphabets" under this i have 'n' number of subfolders. I want to extract the 'n' subfolder names into excel/or any file using python.

alphabets #main folder
  abc #subfolder1
  def #subfolder2
  . 
  .
  . 
  xyz #subfoldern

I want the output as :
abc
def
.
.
.
xyz

Comment: Maybe this could help: [Getting a list of all subdirectories in the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory)

Comment: Yes, I have reviewed that page earlier but it will give the whole sub-directory path not the sub-folder name. I have tried to split the path but couldnt achieve it. I just want to export only the sub-folder name. @JanKoci

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look a python **pathlib** module and consider again Jan Koci answer. It should help you to get a directory name from a directory path.

**os.path** module can help you too by providing the method **basename** to a string representing a path.

Take a look also at **os.path.split**.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is can be easily accomplished using os module.

here is an example code-

```
import os

path = "...\\xyz\\alphabets"
files = os.listdir(path)

with open('file_name.txt', 'a') as f:
    for ele in files:
        f.write(ele+'\n')
    f.close()
print('completed!!')
```