# Get all subdirectories quickly with Python

Tags: python, subdirectory, os.walk

I know the question of how to list all sub-directories in a given directories is answered [in this question from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory). It includes this accepted solution:

```
subdirs = [x[0] for x in os.walk(dirToSearch)]
```

That works fine when there are only a few files in the directory. However I am trying to use this on folders that contain thousands of files, and `os.walk` is apparently iterating over all of them, meaning it takes a really long time to run. Is there a way to do this (identify all subdirectories) without getting bogged down by the files? An alternative to `os.walk` that ignores files?

I'm trying to do this on a Windows network directory.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pathlib` for this.

This will get all immediate subdirectories:

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('.')
subdirs = [x for x in p.iterdir() if x.is_dir()]
```

This will get all nested subdirectories:

```
for subdir in p.glob('**/'):
     print(subdir.name)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. I updated my answer, in case you needed both immediate subdirectories, or all nested subdirectories.

Comment: Hmm I spoke too soon. Although your first method works great for looking in immediate subdirectories, your method to get all nested subdirectories doesn't appear to be any faster than other methods. Any ideas?