# Using os.path.exists and assert to check if a other folders exists besides defined list

Tags: python

For example, my folder structure is:

- `original/dev`
- `original/prd`

(note that `dev` and `prd` are folders and not files)

I would like to check if within the `original` folder is there anything else besides my desired `dev` and `prd` folders. My problem is that this undesired folder could have any name.

What I had in mind for the first part:

```
assert os.path.exists(os.path.join('tests','testvars','dev')) # it works
assert os.path.exists(os.path.join('tests','testvars','prod')) # it works
```

```
# It does not work. Just an idea:
assert os.path.exists(os.path.join('tests','testvars',"anything besides prd && dev"))
```

As you can notice, this last part would throw an assert error other folders (besides `prd` and `dev`) exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a list of all subdirectories in the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory)

Comment: Why does `assert os.path.exists(os.path.join('tests','testvars','dev'))` work if it does not include a `original` component? - and my suggestion is the same as @RandomDavis...you should get a list of everything in the `original` directory, iterate over that list, and do whatever is appropriate if you get anything but `dev` and `prd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just do this:

```
import os
other_dir = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if x != 'dev' and x!='prd']
```

with this you'll end up with a list of all other directory content except `dev` and `prod`

Comment: Building up from this answer and my need to use assert, I ended up using '''assert len([x for x in os.listdir(path) if x != 'dev' and x!='prd']) == 0'''. This will will throw an assert error if there is another folder besides "dev" and "prd".