# Python OS - using 'os.listdir' to view a directory that returns a list of folders. How do I view the contents of the subfolders?

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, subdirectory

I have been set a challenge to browse a directory that contains mostly empty folders - the flag(answer) is in one of them. I have used os module to see all the names of the folders - they are all named 'folder-' plus a number between 1 and 200. How do I view what is inside them?

Comment: You might wan't to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/973488/12203337

Comment: Add more details to your question by providing what you've tried so far.

Comment: I did, I said that I was using os.listdir() but wanted to view the contents of the folders it returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use os.walk() instead of litdir() like as

```
import os
import os.path

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
    for file in filenames:
        print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
def getListOfFiles(dirName):
# create a list of file and sub directories 
# names in the given directory 
File_list = os.listdir(dirName)
Files = list()
# Iterate over all the entries
for entry in File_list:
    # Create full path
    fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
    # If entry is a directory then get the list of files in this directory 
    if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
        Files = Files + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
    else:
        Files.append(fullPath)
            
return Files


#Call the above function to create a list of files in a directory tree i.e.
dirName = 'C:/Users/huzi95s/Desktop/Django';
# Get the list of all files in directory tree at given path
listOfFiles = getListOfFiles(dirName)
```