# Iterating through directories in Python

Tags: python

I have a directory with a bunch of subdirectories. I wish to run a loop that will run through all these files in such a way that it will execute a section of code before moving onto the next subdirectory. In essence, I wish to still treat the files within each subdirectory a separate from those in a another subdirectory. Does anyone know how this might be done?

Comment: Sounds like you want to `walk` down the directories. Hint.

Comment: This may help: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/973488/12229158](https://stackoverflow.com/a/973488/12229158)