# Output subdirectories to pandas .csv using glob

Tags: python, pandas, csv, glob, subdirectory

I'm running a routine that opens a directory, and all its sub-directories, performs some tasks, then outputs to a .csv using pandas. However, I need to establish the sub-directory name, so it can be output to the .csv too.

Accessing a single subdirectory, I can do this with:

```
path = r'/users/directory/sub-directory'
dataframe['sub-directory'] = os.path.basename(path)
print (dataframe)

A B C sub-directory
1 2 3 Folder-1
4 5 6 Folder-1
7 8 9 Folder-1
```

And the sub-directory is easily assinged with `os.path.basename(path)`. However, I want to run through the directory, which works using Glob, but I lose the sub-directory names when outputting to a .csv:

```
path = r'/users/directory/*/' #Using Glob
dataframe['sub-directory'] = os.path.basename(path)
print (dataframe)

#Actual Output
A B C sub-directory
1 2 3 NaN
4 5 6 NaN
7 8 9 NaN
1 2 3 NaN
4 5 6 NaN
7 8 9 NaN

#Desired Output
A B C sub-directory
1 2 3 Folder-1
4 5 6 Folder-1
7 8 9 Folder-1
1 2 3 Folder-2
4 5 6 Folder-3
7 8 9 Folder 4
```

I've seen this answer here: [Getting a list of all subdirectories in the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory), but not sure how to integrate it into my routine.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import glob

path = glob.glob(r'/users/directory/*')
dataframe['sub-directory']=[os.path.basename(i) for i in path]
```

Comment: Nope it throws "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index"

Comment: @SachinReddy Make sure your initialization of the dataframe is correct

Comment: Not sure this is the right approach. Print ([os.path.basename(i) for i in path]) gives: [ 'u','s','e','r','s','','d','i'... etc]. It doesnt get the individual sub-directory/folder names

Comment: @SachinReddy I've edited my answer, check once

Comment: I'm still confused with the folder structure, please clarify

Comment: Directory-1 > Sub-1 > Data '1.dat', '2.dat', '3.dat' and Directory-1 > Sub-2 > Data '1.dat', '2.dat', '3.dat' Directory-1 > Sub-3 > Data '1.dat', '2.dat', '3.dat' and so on. What I need is names Sub-1, Sub-2, Sub-3, so I can output them to the .csv Glob.Glob doesn't work either: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226914/discussion-between-sachinreddy-and-suhas-mucherla).