# How do I display the names of all the subdirectories inside a directory, without using a loop in Python?

Tags: python, directory

I have tried `os.listdir()` but it shows all the files & directories. I've tried other solutions but they mostly require a loop and I am finding ways to do it without a loop.

Comment: Use glob: `glob('./*/')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a list of all subdirectories in the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory)

Comment: Why don't you want to use a loop? Why does "but it shows all the files & directories." not suit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.walk`

```py
import os
subdirs = next(os.walk('.'))[1]
print(subdirs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Works with me:

```
import os

os.mkdir('f')
os.mkdir(r'f/file1')
os.mkdir(r'f/file2')
os.mkdir(r'f/file3')

os.mkdir('f/file1/abc')
os.mkdir('f/file2/def')
os.mkdir('f/file3/ghi')

os.listdir('f')
```

OT:

```
['file2', 'file3', 'file1']
```

listdir with a file

```
os.listdir('f/file1')
```

OT:

```
['abc']
```