# How to get the full file path including the directory?

Tags: python, list, path, operating-system, filepath

I have a quiet complex problem. I have multiple filenames in a list, the root directory of those files is the same: `mother_directory`. However every file has a different subdirectory. Now I have a script which is processing some files and I need to know the exact full path including the subdirectories of every file. I know that I could use `os.walk` but that will make my function too nested as inside this function I'm planning to use another function which uses those full paths.

**This is the file structure:**

```
mother_directory:
               |_child1:
                      20211011.xml
                      20211001.xml
               |_child2:
                      20211002.xml
```

**This is my current code:**

```
mother_path = r'c:\data\user1\Desktop\mother_directory'

blue_dates = ['20211011', '20211012', '20211013', '20211001', '20211002']
red_dates =  ['20211011', '20211009', '20211008', '20211001', '20211002']
file_names = ['20211011.xml', '20211001.xml', '20211002.xml']

def process_files(x):
  if x in red_dates:
    match_file = [s for s in file_names if x in s] 
    file_path = os.path.join(mother_path, match_file [0])
    print(file_path)

for x in blue_dates:
  process_files(x)
```

**My current output:**

```
c:\data\user1\Desktop\mother_directory\20211011.xml
c:\data\user1\Desktop\mother_directory\20211001.xml
c:\data\user1\Desktop\mother_directory\20211002.xml
```

**When I run my function I want my desired output to be like this:**

```
c:\data\user1\Desktop\mother_directory\child1\20211011.xml
c:\data\user1\Desktop\mother_directory\child1\20211001.xml
c:\data\user1\Desktop\mother_directory\child2\20211002.xml
```

Comment: I believe you'll find your answer here. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory)

Comment: @alphaBetaGamma I checked that link out already, done that but I constantly get `child1` as directory while my last file is placed in `child2`

Comment: What do you mean using `os.walk` would make the function too nested?

Comment: @martineau if I use os.walk I will need to use a loop and when I print file_path then I get the file_path printed to many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a condition, I believe it will work now.

```
def process_files(x):
    if x in red_dates:
        match_file = [s for s in file_names if x in s]
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mother_path):
            for file in files:
                if match_file[0] in file:
                    print(os.path.join(root,match_file[0]))
```