# Rename folders using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

A folder named `Folder` have several sub folder `Sub Folder A`, `Sub Folder B` and `Sub Folder C`

I want to make them `sub folder a`, `sub folder b` and `sub folder c`

Is there any way to that?

Comment: You could check this out if it helps?  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_rename.htm

Comment: Why "*using pandas*"? Can you be more explicit (are you talking about actual folders or strings?), because now your question sounds a bit like "*How can I fry eggs using my bike?*" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can use shutil.move(old_path, new_path).

```py
import shutil

old_path = r"C:\Users\adj\Desktop\root_dir\Sub Folder A"
new_path = r"C:\Users\adj\Desktop\root_dir\sub folder a"

shutil.move(old_path, new_path)
```

But based on your example, maybe you just want to lower case the folders name? Then you can use os.rename() and the lower() method

```py
import os

root_folder = r"C:\Users\adj\Desktop\root_dir"
for f in os.listdir(root_folder):
    f_path = os.path.join(root_folder, f)
    os.rename(f_path, f_path.lower())
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is a function in pandas to do that. However the method os.rename() should do the trick when used in combination with os.walk(directory):

- [Getting a list of all subdirectories in the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory)
- [os.rename()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-rename-method/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need pandas here, you can rename with os.rename(folder, newname).

```py
import os

os.rename(folder, new_name)
```

You need the exact path to the folder, for example, 'Folder/FolderA'