# How to find the size of all files in a directory and all its sub-directories?

Tags: python, directory

I'm trying to print the name and the size of all files in a directory and all its sub-directories, but it only prints the name and size of the files in the first directory but not the sub-directories. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()
walk_method = os.walk(path)
while True:
    try:
        p, sub_dir, files = next(walk_method)
        break
    except:
        break
size_of_file = [
    (f, os.stat(os.path.join(path, f)).st_size)
    for f in files
]
for sub in sub_dir:
    i = os.path.join(path, sub)
    size = 0
    for k in os.listdir(i):
        size += os.stat(os.path.join(i, k)).st_size
    size_of_file.append((sub, size))
for f, s in sorted(size_of_file, key = lambda x: x[1]):
    print("{} : {}MB".format(os.path.join(path, f), round(s/(1024*1024), 3)))
```

I'm expecting to print the name and file size of all files in the current directory and all the sub-directories.

Comment: You'll need to recursively walk through all the `sub_dirs`; I might suggest making a `set` of `sub_dirs` and adding to that set every time you find a directory, and popping from that set to walk through it; keep walking/adding/popping until the set is empty. (Might need to also check against an `already_visited` set to make sure you don't get stuck in a symlink-loop.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a list of all subdirectories in the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)
has some helpful example code
that you might have chosen to follow.
A loop forever / next() / break approach could be
made to work, I'm sure, but it's not idiomatic
and that style does not improve the maintainability
of the code.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

total = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for file in files:
        path = Path(root) / file
        print(path)
        total += path.stat().st_size

print(f"Total of {total} bytes.")
```

Answer (score 0):

pathlib is amazing here I think, there are many ways of solving this but one simple example is something like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path

dir = "."
paths = list(Path(dir).glob('**/*'))
for path in paths:
    if path.is_file():
        print(f"{path.name}, {path.lstat().st_size}")
```

You don't need the loop but for simplicity in this example I just used it.