# Tkinter Combo Box, how to show all the folders in a parent folder and store it for later use

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I can't seem to figure out how to make the Combo Box list all of the folders in the parent "soundpacks" folder. I need them to show, and being able to choose one is an integral part of the app I'm building.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry("400x600")
root.title("VibesPlus")

logo = Image.open('img/download.png')
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo)

logo_label = tk.Label(root, image=logo)
logo_label.pack()

folder_path = "C:/Users/konel/Documents/Source/VibesPlus/soundpacks"
combo = ttk.Combobox(root, height=20, width=200, values=[folder_path])
combo.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Here's what I have so far, and the combobox only shows the main folder's path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

You wrote `values=[folder_path])` which includes only the path, but a `loop` would be needed using the `os.walk()` method.

### Solution

Instead you have to create a compressed loop, so that it takes the first element `[0]` of the files in a tree. The `os.walk()` method does just that, because it generates file names in a tree by walking up the tree down or down the tree.

For understanding purposes, i write the uncompressed loop:

```
for a in os.walk(folder_path):
    a[0]
```

but actually compressed it should be `[a[0] for a in os.walk(folder_path)])`, so the solution is `values=[a[0] for a in os.walk(folder_path)])`

Here is the solution for how to show all folders in one root folder and store it for later use

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry("400x600")
root.title("VibesPlus")

logo = Image.open('img/download.png')
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo)

logo_label = tk.Label(root, image=logo)
logo_label.pack()

folder_path = "C:/Users/konel/Documents/Source/VibesPlus/soundpacks"
combo = ttk.Combobox(root, height=20, width=200, values=[a[0] for a in os.walk(folder_path)])
combo.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I just tested this, but it shows the whole directory in the combobox. How can I make it so that it only shows the folder names?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could just use :

```
combo = ttk.Combobox(root, height=20, width=200, values=[x[0] for x in os.walk(folder_path)])
```

This subject has been answered more in detail here:

[getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory)

Try to search on stackoverflow next time if your question has not been answered yet. :)

Comment: I looked around but couldn't find the solution you posted. Thank you!