# Read images in folder's folder in jupyterlab

Tags: python, file, jupyter-lab

I have a folder called kaggle, inside has a folder called PetImages, inside I have two folder called Dog and Cat.
I used the code as follows, said that the file or directory not exist, but I am sure that the file path is correctly.

```
import cv2
import os

def load_images_from_folder(foldername):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(foldername):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(foldername,filename))
        if img is not None:
            images.append(img)
    return images

folder_path = 'C:/Users/1234/Downloads/kaggle/PetImages'
images = load_images_from_folder(folder_path)
```

Comment: So if you have two folders containing your images within 'C:/Users/1234/Downloads/kaggle/PetImages',  then you're passing to `cv2.imread` the name of the folder which won't work. You need to append each of the directory to `C:/Users/1234/Downloads/kaggle/PetImages` then pass it to `load_images_from_folder`

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use `pathlib`, since the iterator returns the full PosixPath of the files:

```py
from pathlib import Path
images = [cv2.imread(p) for p in Path(foldername).glob('**/*')]
```

You can drop the `None` values later.
Works both on Windows and Unix systems.

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/38245063/5316326