# Non-alphanumeric list order from os.listdir()

Tags: python, list, directory-listing, listdir

I often use python to process directories of data. Recently, I have noticed that the default order of the lists has changed to something almost nonsensical. For example, if I am in a current directory containing the following subdirectories: run01, run02, ... run19, run20, and then I generate a list from the following command:

```
dir = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
```

then I usually get a list in this order:

```
dir = ['run01', 'run18', 'run14', 'run13', 'run12', 'run11', 'run08', ... ]
```

and so on. The order used to be alphanumeric. But this new order has remained with me for a while now.

What is determining the (displayed) order of these lists?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I think the order has to do with the way the files are indexed on your FileSystem.
If you really want to make it adhere to some order you can always sort the list after getting the files.

Answer (score 248):

You can use the builtin `sorted` function to sort the strings however you want.  Based on what you describe,

```
sorted(os.listdir(whatever_directory))
```

Alternatively, you can use the `.sort` method of a list:

```
lst = os.listdir(whatever_directory)
lst.sort()
```

I think should do the trick.

Note that the order that `os.listdir` gets the filenames is probably completely dependent on your filesystem.

Comment: Does not change the order if dealing with number-first filenames (ie 59.9780radps-0096 is still before 9.9746radps-0082). I think it's because everything is a string, so the decimal is not treated properly.

Comment: @Elliot -- Correct, It's sorting lexicographically as strings.  To get it to sort some other way, you'd need to define a `key` function that determined the sort order.  In your case, you'd want the key function to look at the string and return `59.9780` or `9.9746` (as `float`) for your filenames respectively.

Comment: Or use the natsort library, which I just found.

Comment: Only `sorted(listdir)` worked for me. `listdir.sort()` gave me: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @paul_h -- `listdir.sort()` won't work for statements like `for i in listdir.sort()`, because `list.sort()` method change the order of items in lists **IN PLACE**, which means process the list itself but won't return anything but `None`. So you need to use `a_list = listdir('some_path'); a_list.sort()` then do `for i in a_list`

Comment: Do you know how to change the order to ascending or descending using `.sort` ?

Comment: @AlexB -- sure ... just pass `reverse=True` to make it descending sort.

Comment: @mgilson is it possible to do it in like one line? something like `lst = os.listdir(whatever_directory).sort()` - this of course will just make lst = None, but do we need to do it in two lines?

Comment: @user3895596 -- I think that the `sorted` thing written first does it in a single line OK?

Comment: You can use key in sorted to parse more complex filenames. A simple example of sorting a list like this `['0001.txt', '0002.txt']` is: `sorted(os.listdir(path), key=lambda filename: int(filename.split('.')[0]))`

Answer (score 64):

Per the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=listdir#os.listdir):

> os.listdir(path)
>
> > Return a list
> >     containing the names of the entries in
> >     the directory given by path. **The list
> >     is in arbitrary order**. It does not
> >     include the special entries '.' and
> >     '..' even if they are present in the
> >     directory.

Order cannot be relied upon and is an artifact of the filesystem.

To sort the result, use `sorted(os.listdir(path))`.

Answer (score 63):

Python for whatever reason does not come with a built-in way to have **natural sorting** (meaning 1, 2, 10 instead of 1, 10, 2), so you have to write it yourself:

```
import re
def sorted_alphanumeric(data):
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ] 
    return sorted(data, key=alphanum_key)
```

You can now use this function to sort a list:

```
dirlist = sorted_alphanumeric(os.listdir(...))
```

---

**PROBLEMS:**
In case you use the above function to sort strings (for example folder names) and want them sorted like Windows Explorer does, it will not work properly in some edge cases.
This sorting function will return incorrect results on Windows, if you have folder names with certain 'special' characters in them. For example this function will sort `1, !1, !a, a`, whereas Windows Explorer would sort `!1, 1, !a, a`.

So if you want to **sort exactly like Windows Explorer does in Python** you have to use the Windows built-in function [StrCmpLogicalW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strcmplogicalw) via ctypes (this of course won't work on Unix):

```
from ctypes import wintypes, windll
from functools import cmp_to_key

def winsort(data):
    _StrCmpLogicalW = windll.Shlwapi.StrCmpLogicalW
    _StrCmpLogicalW.argtypes = [wintypes.LPWSTR, wintypes.LPWSTR]
    _StrCmpLogicalW.restype  = wintypes.INT

    cmp_fnc = lambda psz1, psz2: _StrCmpLogicalW(psz1, psz2)
    return sorted(data, key=cmp_to_key(cmp_fnc))
```

This function is slightly slower than `sorted_alphanumeric()`.

Bonus: `winsort` can also **sort full paths on Windows**.

Alternatively, especially if you use Unix, you can use the `natsort` library (`pip install natsort`) to sort by full paths in a correct way (meaning subfolders at the correct position).

You can use it like this to sort full paths:

```
from natsort import natsorted, ns
dirlist = natsorted(dirlist, alg=ns.PATH | ns.IGNORECASE)
```

Starting with version 7.1.0 natsort supports [`os_sorted`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#natsort.os_sorted) which internally uses either the beforementioned Windows API or Linux sorting and should be used instead of `natsorted()`.

Comment: Works perfectly fine. `print( sorted_aphanumeric(["1", "10", "2", "foo_10", "foo_8"]) )` -> `['1', '2', '10', 'foo_8', 'foo_10']`. Exactly as expected.

Comment: There is a longstanding open issue on `natsorted` to get Windows Explorer matching functionality implemented. Perhaps you should contribute a solution? https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort/issues/41

Comment: The winsort function was exactly what I needed :)

Comment: worked great on files name finishing a _1, _2,..._10, _11, etc

Comment: This is really helpful!

Answer (score 22):

I think by default the order is determined with the ASCII value. The solution to this problem is this

```
dir = sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd()), key=len)
```

Comment: None of the above worked for me, that "key-len" seemed to be the last remaining trick, thanks so much.

Answer (score 13):

**Use `natsort` library:**

Install the library with the following command for Ubuntu and other Debian versions

**Python 2**

```
sudo pip install natsort
```

**Python 3**

```
sudo pip3 install natsort
```

Details of how to use this library is found [here](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/)

```py
from natsort import natsorted

files = ['run01', 'run18', 'run14', 'run13', 'run12', 'run11', 'run08']
natsorted(files)

[out]:
['run01', 'run08', 'run11', 'run12', 'run13', 'run14', 'run18']
```

- This is not a duplicate of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48030307/7758804). `natsort` was added as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48030307/4) on 2020-01-27.

Comment: That is more accurate than `sorted()`! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's probably just the order that C's `readdir()` returns.  Try running this C program:

```c
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
   DIR *dirp;
   struct dirent* de;
   dirp = opendir(".");
   while(de = readdir(dirp)) // Yes, one '='.
        printf("%s\n", de->d_name);
   closedir(dirp);
   return 0;
}
```

The build line should be something like `gcc -o foo foo.c`.

P.S. Just ran this and your Python code, and they both gave me sorted output, so I can't reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: The reason that you're seeing soted output may depend on a lot of factors, such as OS, filesystem, time of creation of files, actions during the last defragmentation, ...

Answer (score 5):

```
aaa = ['row_163.pkl', 'row_394.pkl', 'row_679.pkl', 'row_202.pkl', 'row_1449.pkl', 'row_247.pkl', 'row_1353.pkl', 'row_749.pkl', 'row_1293.pkl', 'row_1304.pkl', 'row_78.pkl', 'row_532.pkl', 'row_9.pkl', 'row_1435.pkl']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
sorted(aaa, key=lambda x: int(os.path.splitext(x.split('_')[1])[0]))
```

As In case of mine requirement I have the case like `row_163.pkl` here `os.path.splitext('row_163.pkl')` will break it into `('row_163', '.pkl')` so need to split it based on '_' also.

but in case of your requirement you can do something like

```
sorted(aa, key = lambda x: (int(re.sub('\D','',x)),x))
```

where

```
aa = ['run01', 'run08', 'run11', 'run12', 'run13', 'run14', 'run18']
```

and also for directory retrieving you can do `sorted(os.listdir(path))`

and for the case of like `'run01.txt'` or `'run01.csv'` you can do like this

```
sorted(files, key=lambda x : int(os.path.splitext(x)[0]))
```

Comment: Unarguably best answer here.

Answer (score 3):

The proposed combination of `os.listdir` and `sorted` commands generates the same result as `ls -l` command under Linux. The following example verifies this assumption:

```
user@user-PC:/tmp/test$ touch 3a 4a 5a b c d1 d2 d3 k l p0 p1 p3 q 410a 409a 408a 407a
user@user-PC:/tmp/test$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 3a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 407a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 408a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 409a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 410a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 4a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 5a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 b
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 d1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 d2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 d3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 k
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 p0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 p1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 p3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  15 10:31 q

user@user-PC:/tmp/test$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir( './' )
['d3', 'k', 'p1', 'b', '410a', '5a', 'l', 'p0', '407a', '409a', '408a', 'd2', '4a', 'p3', '3a', 'q', 'c', 'd1']
>>> sorted( os.listdir( './' ) )
['3a', '407a', '408a', '409a', '410a', '4a', '5a', 'b', 'c', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'k', 'l', 'p0', 'p1', 'p3', 'q']
>>> exit()
user@user-PC:/tmp/test$
```

So, for someone who wants to reproduce the result of the well-known `ls -l` command in their python code, `sorted( os.listdir( DIR ) )` works pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir):

> **The list is in arbitrary order**, and does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.

This means that the order is probably OS/filesystem dependent, has no particularly meaningful order, and is therefore not guaranteed to be anything in particular. As many answers mentioned: if preferred, the retrieved list can be sorted.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

I found "sort" does not always do what I expected. eg, I have a directory as below, and the "sort" give me a very strange result:

```
>>> os.listdir(pathon)
['2', '3', '4', '5', '403', '404', '407', '408', '410', '411', '412', '413', '414', '415', '416', '472']
>>> sorted([ f for f in os.listdir(pathon)])
['2', '3', '4', '403', '404', '407', '408', '410', '411', '412', '413', '414', '415', '416', '472', '5']
```

It seems it compares the first character first, if that is the biggest, it would be the last one.

Comment: This is expected behavior. `('5' > '403') is True`.

Comment: @AXO is correct, because at this point you're comparing the alphanumeric sort, not quantitative values of the numbers. In order to get a sort similar to your expectation, you may want to use number padding on your folders... ['002', '003', '004', '005', '403', '404', '405', '406']

Comment: Don't use padding, just use a string to number conversion as sorting key: `sorted(os.listdir(pathon), key=int)` will properly return `['2', '3', '4', '5', '403', ...]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [6]: os.listdir?

Type:       builtin_function_or_method
String Form:<built-in function listdir>
Docstring:
listdir(path) -> list_of_strings
Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory.
path: path of directory to list
The list is in **arbitrary order**.  It does not include the special
entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.
```

Comment: This explains why they are seeing the behaviour, without offering a solution.

Comment: OP just want to know why, not how.

Comment: @Denis thanks for pointing this out - I didn't notice it before

Comment: @DanielWatkins OK, Not it isnt.)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question directly, you can use the following code.

```
dir = ['run01', 'run18', 'run14', 'run13', 'run12', 'run11', 'run08']
for file in sorted(dir, key=lambda x:int(x.replace('run', ''))):
    print(file)
```

It will print:

```sh
run01
run08
run11
run12
run13
run14
run18
```

This approach uses the Python built-in method `sorted`, and, through the `key` argument, it specifies the sorting criterium, that is, the list item without 'run' casted to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

`ls` by default previews the files sorted by name. (`ls` options can be used to sort by date, size, ...)

```
files = list(os.popen("ls"))
files = [file.strip("\n") for file in files]
```

Using `ls` would have much better performance when the directory contains so many files.