# In what order does os.walk iterates iterate?

Tags: python, sorting, os.walk

I am concerned about the order of files and directories given by `os.walk()`. If I have these directories, `1`, `10`, `11`, `12`, `2`, `20`, `21`, `22`, `3`, `30`, `31`, `32`, what is the order of the output list?

Is it sorted by numeric values?

```
1 2 3 10 20 30 11 21 31 12 22 32
```

Or sorted by ASCII values, like what is given by `ls`?

```
1 10 11 12 2 20 21 22 3 30 31 32
```

Additionally, how can I get a specific sort?

Comment: Why not `touch` those files or `mkdir` those directories (you can do either all on one line) and find out?

Comment: FYI: On Linux/ext3 this is currently the same as `ls -U`.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

`os.walk` uses `os.listdir`. Here is the docstring for `os.listdir`:

> listdir(path) -> list_of_strings
>
> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory.
>
> ```
> path: path of directory to list
> ```
>
> **The list is in arbitrary order**.  It does not include the special
>   entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.

(my emphasis).

You could, however, use `sort` to ensure the order you desire.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
   for dirname in sorted(dirs):
        print(dirname)
```

(Note the dirnames are strings not ints, so `sorted(dirs)` sorts them as strings -- which is desirable for once.

As Alfe and Ciro Santilli point out, if you want the directories to be *recursed* in sorted order, then modify `dirs` *in-place*:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
   dirs.sort()
   for dirname in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(root, dirname))
```

---

You can test this yourself:

```
import os

os.chdir('/tmp/tmp')
for dirname in '1 10 11 12 2 20 21 22 3 30 31 32'.split():
     try:
          os.makedirs(dirname)
     except OSError: pass


for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
   for dirname in sorted(dirs):
        print(dirname)
```

prints

```
1
10
11
12
2
20
21
22
3
30
31
32
```

If you wanted to list them in numeric order use:

```
for dirname in sorted(dirs, key=int):
```

To sort alphanumeric strings, use [natural sort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5967500/190597).

Comment: The reason Python goes out of its way to avoid documenting any reliable order is that it uses different functions on different platforms (`FindNextFileW`, `DosFindNext`, `readdir`), and those functions are themselves documented to punt to the filesystem on most platforms, and the filesystems generally either don't document an order or give you something completely useless.

Comment: I think this does not sort multi level hierarchies because `sorted` is not in-place. To do that use `sort` as explained by Alfe.

Comment: Why `dirs.sort()` works? For answer see the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#:~:text=When%20topdown%20is,itself%20is%20generated.

Answer (score 54):

`os.walk()` yields in each step what it will do in the next steps.  You can in each step influence the order of the next steps by sorting the lists the way you want them.  Quoting [the 2.7 manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk):

> When topdown is True, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place (perhaps using del or slice assignment), and walk() will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting

So sorting the `dirNames` will influence the order in which they will be visited:

```
for rootName, dirNames, fileNames in os.walk(path):
  dirNames.sort()  # you may want to use the args cmp, key and reverse here
```

After this, the `dirNames` are sorted in-place and the next yielded values of `walk` will be accordingly.

Of course you also can sort the list of `fileNames` but that won't influence any further steps (because files don't have descendants `walk` will visit).

And of course you can iterate through sorted versions of these lists as unutbu's answer proposes, but that won't influence the further progress of the `walk` itself.

The unmodified order of the values is undefined by `os.walk`, meaning that it will be "any" order.  You should not rely on what you experience today.  But in fact it will probably be what the underlying file system returns.  In some file systems this will be alphabetically ordered.

Comment: Downvoter: Please comment on what you didn't like.

Comment: To have *natural sorting* (1, 2, 10), have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48030307/2441026

Comment: I got it at the end. The trick is that on the first level of iteration where is only one single rootName which does not need to be sorted. Every next rootName is inside already-sorted dirNames of that toplevel rootName which guarantees proper recursive sort and in-place modification possibility at the same time!

Answer (score 50):

The simplest way is to sort the return values of `os.walk()`, e.g. using:

```
for rootName, dirNames, fileNames in sorted(os.walk(path)):
    #root, dirs and files are iterated in order...
```

Comment: I don't know why are people ignoring this answer, it's the cleanest and simplest solution... TY

Comment: sadly this didn't work for me :(

Comment: I required both this and sorting of the lists I was interested in (fileNames in my case). Then it worked consistently across platforms. Thanks :)

Comment: This will first collect all values the `os.walk()` delivers into a list, then sort that list, then run the `for` loop.  This list can become very large.  Collecting it can take a lot of time.  Effectively the advantages of the generator-features of `os.walk()` are destroyed by this.  Sorting the results for each directory in-place (see my answer) may seem a little more complicated but I think keeping the generator-advantages is worth the effort.

Comment: I used this to sort directories and files :                                                  
                                                                                                               
for subdir, dirs, files in sorted(os.walk(rootDir)):
    for file in sorted(files):

Comment: This sorts the individual yield returns, but does not sort recursively by root path if you're yielding the return values in a function. E.g., if you were returning `for f in files: yield root + f`, the result of the function wouldn't be sorted.

Comment: You can always use `os.walk()` with internal sorting instead. `for path,dirs,files in sorted(os.walk(...)): work()` results always in the same as `for path,dirs,files in os.walk(...): \\ dirs.sort() \\ files.sort() \\ work()` (the `\\ ` being newlines).  (Of course that `sorted(walk)` cannot be meant verbatim, but I guess you understand what I mean.)  The sorting always can take place in the iteration itself.

Comment: @Alfe, you are right. The internal sorting works for all cases. Just simple sorted(os.walk()) makes in-place modification impossible which is serious disadvantage.