# How can I calculate a hash for a filesystem-directory using Python?

Tags: python, hash

I'm using this code to calculate hash value for a file:

```
m = hashlib.md5()
with open("calculator.pdf", 'rb') as fh:
    while True:
        data = fh.read(8192)
        if not data:
            break
        m.update(data)
    hash_value = m.hexdigest()

    print  hash_value
```

when I tried it on a folder "folder"I got

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: folder
```

How could I calculate the hash value for a folder ?

Comment: For what purpose? Unique identification? Use the full folder path or inode. To identify its contents? Then iterate through its full contents and hash that.

Comment: You must calculate the hash value of all its files and the files of its subfolders.

Comment: Konrad's correct in that there's lots of ambiguity in the question.  Another possibility he hasn't listed is hashing the directory entry meta-data, which could be used for a quick/rough check whether content has changed.  BTW, some OSes do let you "open" a directory much as if it was a text file and the code above for files would already "work" for whatever metadata the directory "file" stream produced.  As is, the question deserves to be closed unless the need or aim is clarified.

Comment: There's [this gist](https://gist.github.com/techtonik/5175896) with an imo cleaner code. There's also a designated package [checksumdir](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/checksumdir) and [dirtools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dirtools) that has hashing-capabilities.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [Recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576973-getting-the-sha-1-or-md5-hash-of-a-directory/) provides a nice function to do what you are asking. I've modified it to use the MD5 hash, instead of the SHA1, as your original question asks

```
def GetHashofDirs(directory, verbose=0):
  import hashlib, os
  SHAhash = hashlib.md5()
  if not os.path.exists (directory):
    return -1

  try:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
      for names in files:
        if verbose == 1:
          print 'Hashing', names
        filepath = os.path.join(root,names)
        try:
          f1 = open(filepath, 'rb')
        except:
          # You can't open the file for some reason
          f1.close()
          continue

        while 1:
          # Read file in as little chunks
          buf = f1.read(4096)
          if not buf : break
          SHAhash.update(hashlib.md5(buf).hexdigest())
        f1.close()

  except:
    import traceback
    # Print the stack traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
    return -2

  return SHAhash.hexdigest()
```

You can use it like this:

```
print GetHashofDirs('folder_to_hash', 1)
```

The output looks like this, as it hashes each file:

```
...
Hashing file1.cache
Hashing text.txt
Hashing library.dll
Hashing vsfile.pdb
Hashing prog.cs
5be45c5a67810b53146eaddcae08a809
```

The returned value from this function call comes back as the hash. In this case, `5be45c5a67810b53146eaddcae08a809`

Comment: What is intented for the `import traceback` ?

Comment: @begueradj, In this case, [traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc), is used to print the stacktrace if an error occurs while hashing

Comment: Just ignoring a file you couldn't open doesn't sound as at the correct approach to me. Furthermore, [you cannot guarantee](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18282401/2436175) e.g. on different filesystems that os.walk will navigate the files in the same order.

Comment: Is this recursive?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist yes it is because [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) is.

Comment: Using Python 3.5.4, this solution did not work for me, until I had changed .hexdigest() to .digest() in the SHAhas.update line. Was I doing something wrong, or was this a mistake?

Comment: I know it's old, but I had to downvote this since both try..except blocks in this are broken, apart from the mentioned problems like os.walk not being stable.

Comment: I also know it's old, but I have to point out that writing `except:` is never a good idea.
This will invoke the 'except' block, even if normal exit was invoked with sys.exit(0).

Answer (score 23):

Use checksumdir python package available for calculating checksum/hash of directory. It's available at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/checksumdir

***Usage :***

```
import checksumdir
hash = checksumdir.dirhash("c:\\temp")
print hash
```

Comment: Note: `checksumdir` is not tested (even when claiming to be stable). Using it is (arguably) *less* trustworthy than using the recipe, that at least forces you to read the recipe.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me across different operating systems (getting different hashes under MacOS and Debian) :(

Comment: checksumdir does not include filenames in the hash, so renaming files does not change the hash.

Answer (score 23):

Here is an implementation that uses pathlib.Path instead of relying on os.walk. It sorts the directory contents before iterating so it should be repeatable on multiple platforms. It also updates the hash with the names of files/directories, so adding empty files and directories will change the hash.

Version with type annotations (Python 3.6 or above):

```
import hashlib
from _hashlib import HASH as Hash
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union


def md5_update_from_file(filename: Union[str, Path], hash: Hash) -> Hash:
    assert Path(filename).is_file()
    with open(str(filename), "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            hash.update(chunk)
    return hash


def md5_file(filename: Union[str, Path]) -> str:
    return str(md5_update_from_file(filename, hashlib.md5()).hexdigest())


def md5_update_from_dir(directory: Union[str, Path], hash: Hash) -> Hash:
    assert Path(directory).is_dir()
    for path in sorted(Path(directory).iterdir(), key=lambda p: str(p).lower()):
        hash.update(path.name.encode())
        if path.is_file():
            hash = md5_update_from_file(path, hash)
        elif path.is_dir():
            hash = md5_update_from_dir(path, hash)
    return hash


def md5_dir(directory: Union[str, Path]) -> str:
    return str(md5_update_from_dir(directory, hashlib.md5()).hexdigest())
```

Without type annotations:

```
import hashlib
from pathlib import Path


def md5_update_from_file(filename, hash):
    assert Path(filename).is_file()
    with open(str(filename), "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            hash.update(chunk)
    return hash


def md5_file(filename):
    return md5_update_from_file(filename, hashlib.md5()).hexdigest()


def md5_update_from_dir(directory, hash):
    assert Path(directory).is_dir()
    for path in sorted(Path(directory).iterdir(), key=lambda p: str(p).lower()):
        hash.update(path.name.encode())
        if path.is_file():
            hash = md5_update_from_file(path, hash)
        elif path.is_dir():
            hash = md5_update_from_dir(path, hash)
    return hash


def md5_dir(directory):
    return md5_update_from_dir(directory, hashlib.md5()).hexdigest()
```

Condensed version if you only need to hash directories:

```
def md5_update_from_dir(directory, hash):
    assert Path(directory).is_dir()
    for path in sorted(Path(directory).iterdir(), key=lambda p: str(p).lower()):
        hash.update(path.name.encode())
        if path.is_file():
            with open(path, "rb") as f:
                for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
                    hash.update(chunk)
        elif path.is_dir():
            hash = md5_update_from_dir(path, hash)
    return hash


def md5_dir(directory):
    return md5_update_from_dir(directory, hashlib.md5()).hexdigest()
```

Usage: `md5_hash = md5_dir("/some/directory")`

Comment: Is it by design your initializing the hash with the absolute path to the files and not say the relative path from a root directory?

Comment: @nimig18 I'm doing neither; only the file names (without path) are included in the hash.

Comment: The sorting of the files is very important for this to be repeatable as neither Path iterdir or os.walk guarantee a certain ordering and will be subject to the underlying os implementation. However, just sorting by case insensitive paths is not enough, since sorted is in-place and if two folders in linux are different only by case, sorted can return a different order different times depending on the specific order returned by iterdir/os.walk. The proper solution is to sort first by case, and then by case insensitivity. @danmou perhaps you could update this?

Comment: @MatiasGrioni It's been a while since I wrote this code and I don't remember why I did a case-insensitive sort in the first place. Shouldn't a normal case-sensitive sort do the trick?

Comment: It depends on what characteristics you want your hashing to have. There is no "natural" way to hash a folder, so there is some policy / characteristics you should define beforehand for your application and make sure the algorithm works for it.

Comment: So case-sensitive will work on linux, and windows, but it means that changing a folder or file name from "A" to "a" will change the final hash even though from one valid perspective (but not the only one), these are the same filesystem objects.

Comment: Another thing that I came across when using this is that the path.name.encode() hashing also has to be closed out. Otherwise, you don't know the exact structure and two different folder structures can hash the same. For example, (B -> (A), A) will hash the same as (B -> (A, A)). The arrow means folder name to file inside the folder.

Edited: Wrong folder structure should be okay now.

Comment: I am wondering how to speed up by using multi processing. Thanks!

Comment: @HongboMiao I don't think that is possible, because the hash needs to be updated with each file sequentially. You might be able to get some speedup by getting rid of the chunking and reading the whole file at once instead (let me know if it works, I can't remember why I did the chunking in the first place)

Comment: Thanks @danmou for following up! The reason to read as chunk is to help use less memory. I did increase to 1MiB (further increasing won't speed up based on my experiments). I also changed to XXH128 which is ~ 50 times faster. I posted at stackoverflow.com/a/77943341/2000548 Hopefully, one day someone else can find a multi processing solution and post as an answer ☺️

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a fan of how the recipe referenced in the answer was written. I have a much simpler version that I'm using:

```
import hashlib
import os


def hash_directory(path):
    digest = hashlib.sha1()

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for names in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, names)

            # Hash the path and add to the digest to account for empty files/directories
            digest.update(hashlib.sha1(file_path[len(path):].encode()).digest())

            # Per @pt12lol - if the goal is uniqueness over repeatability, this is an alternative method using 'hash'
            # digest.update(str(hash(file_path[len(path):])).encode())

            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                with open(file_path, 'rb') as f_obj:
                    while True:
                        buf = f_obj.read(1024 * 1024)
                        if not buf:
                            break
                        digest.update(buf)

    return digest.hexdigest()
```

I found exceptions were usually being thrown whenever something like an `alias` was encountered (shows up in the `os.walk()`, but you can't directly open it). The `os.path.isfile()` check takes care of those issues.

If there were to be an actual file within a directory I'm attempting to hash and it couldn't be opened, skipping that file and continuing is not a good solution. That affects the outcome of the hash. Better to kill the hash attempt altogether. Here, the `try` statement would be wrapped around the call to my `hash_directory()` function.

```
>>> try:
...   print(hash_directory('/tmp'))
... except:
...   print('Failed!')
... 
e2a075b113239c8a25c7e1e43f21e8f2f6762094
>>>
```

Comment: Good stuff, but note this hash won't change if you add empty file or directory.

Comment: I added `digest.update(str(hash(file_path[len(path):])).encode())` for each `file_path` and `dir_path`. Hash ensures that this hash will be dependent on `PYTHONHASHSEED`, so faking this hash calculation will be really difficult.

Comment: @pt12lol  I really like that idea - I hadn't considered that possibility - but I think using `hash` isn't the right solution. The result for the function will be different between Python 2 and Python 3 (I just tried this on my Mac).


What about using `hashlib` again?


```python
digest.update(hashlib.sha1(file_path.encode()).digest())
```

Comment: No wonder that this hash differs between Python 2 and 3, because Python 3 introduces variable `PYTHONHASHSEED` that differs between every single Python run and `hash` relies on it. I suppose you are asserting directory hash with hardcoded value and `digest` is definitely better in this case. To be honest I don't have my code dependent on hardcoded values so I didn't care about it, only cared about uniqueness. In my case `hash` is even safer than `digest`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for choosing 1024*1024 as the buffer size?

Comment: @Darren I carried this over from some code I wrote to hash very large files (in excess of several GBs). 1MB seemed a sane amount.

Answer (score 3):

I keep seeing this code propagated through various forums.

The [ActiveState recipe answer](/a/24937710) works but, as Antonio pointed out, it is not guaranteed to be repeatable across filesystems, due to not being able to present the files in the same order (try it).  One fix is to change

```python
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
  for names in files:
```

to

```python
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
  for names in sorted(files):
```

(Yes I'm being lazy here.  This sorts the filenames only and not the directories.  The same principle applies)

Answer (score 2):

use the checksumdir https://pypi.org/project/checksumdir/

```
directory  = '/path/to/directory/'
md5hash    = dirhash(directory, 'md5')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have optimized further on Andy's response.

The following is a python3 rather than python2 implementation. It uses SHA1, handles some cases where encoding is needed, is linted, and includes some doctrings.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""dir_hash: Return SHA1 hash of a directory.
- Copyright (c) 2009 Stephen Akiki, 2018 Joe Flack
- MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
- http://akiscode.com/articles/sha-1directoryhash.shtml
"""
import hashlib
import os


def update_hash(running_hash, filepath, encoding=''):
    """Update running SHA1 hash, factoring in hash of given file.

    Side Effects:
        running_hash.update()
    """
    if encoding:
        file = open(filepath, 'r', encoding=encoding)
        for line in file:
            hashed_line = hashlib.sha1(line.encode(encoding))
            hex_digest = hashed_line.hexdigest().encode(encoding)
            running_hash.update(hex_digest)
        file.close()
    else:
        file = open(filepath, 'rb')
        while True:
            # Read file in as little chunks.
            buffer = file.read(4096)
            if not buffer:
                break
            running_hash.update(hashlib.sha1(buffer).hexdigest())
        file.close()


def dir_hash(directory, verbose=False):
    """Return SHA1 hash of a directory.

    Args:
        directory (string): Path to a directory.
        verbose (bool): If True, prints progress updates.

    Raises:
        FileNotFoundError: If directory provided does not exist.

    Returns:
        string: SHA1 hash hexdigest of a directory.
    """
    sha_hash = hashlib.sha1()

    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        raise FileNotFoundError

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for names in files:
            if verbose:
                print('Hashing', names)
            filepath = os.path.join(root, names)
            try:
                update_hash(running_hash=sha_hash,
                            filepath=filepath)
            except TypeError:
                update_hash(running_hash=sha_hash,
                            filepath=filepath,
                            encoding='utf-8')

    return sha_hash.hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much @danmou answer! I did two more improvements to further speed up.

- Update byte_block to 1 MiB (further increase has no speed up)
- Change MD5 to XXH128 which is about 50 times faster than MD5

```py
from pathlib import Path

import xxhash


def calculate_file_xxh128(
    file_path: Path, xxh128_hash: xxhash.xxh3_128
) -> xxhash.xxh3_128:
    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
        # Read 1 MiB at a time to use less memory
        while byte_block := file.read(1024 * 1024):
            xxh128_hash.update(byte_block)
    return xxh128_hash

def calculate_dir_xxh128(
    dir_path: Path, xxh128_hash: xxhash.xxh3_128
) -> xxhash.xxh3_128:
    for path in sorted(Path(dir_path).iterdir(), key=lambda p: str(p).lower()):
        xxh128_hash.update(path.name.encode())
        if path.is_file():
            xxh128_hash = calculate_file_xxh128(path, xxh128_hash)
        elif path.is_dir():
            xxh128_hash = calculate_dir_xxh128(path, xxh128_hash)
    return xxh128_hash

def get_file_xxh128(file_path: Path) -> str:
    return calculate_file_xxh128(file_path, xxhash.xxh128()).hexdigest()

def get_dir_xxh128(dir_path: Path) -> str:
    return calculate_dir_xxh128(dir_path, xxhash.xxh128()).hexdigest()
```

### Usage

```py
file_xxh128 = calculate_file_xxh128(path_to_file)
dir_xxh128 = calculate_dir_xxh128(path_to_dir)
```

The reason to update from MD5 to XXH128 is based on this [benchmark](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash?tab=readme-ov-file#benchmarks). I compared XXH128 and MD5 speed locally which gets same result. XXH128 is slightly slower than XXH3, yet it boasts greater future-proofing, offering an even lower chance of collisions.

| Hash Name | Width | Bandwidth (GB/s) | Small Data Velocity | Quality | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **XXH3** (SSE2) | 64 | 31.5 GB/s | 133.1 | 10 |  |
| **XXH128** (SSE2) | 128 | 29.6 GB/s | 118.1 | 10 |  |
| *RAM sequential read* | N/A | 28.0 GB/s | N/A | N/A | *for reference* |
| City64 | 64 | 22.0 GB/s | 76.6 | 10 |  |
| T1ha2 | 64 | 22.0 GB/s | 99.0 | 9 | Slightly worse [collisions] |
| City128 | 128 | 21.7 GB/s | 57.7 | 10 |  |
| **XXH64** | 64 | 19.4 GB/s | 71.0 | 10 |  |
| SpookyHash | 64 | 19.3 GB/s | 53.2 | 10 |  |
| Mum | 64 | 18.0 GB/s | 67.0 | 9 | Slightly worse [collisions] |
| **XXH32** | 32 | 9.7 GB/s | 71.9 | 10 |  |
| City32 | 32 | 9.1 GB/s | 66.0 | 10 |  |
| Murmur3 | 32 | 3.9 GB/s | 56.1 | 10 |  |
| SipHash | 64 | 3.0 GB/s | 43.2 | 10 |  |
| FNV64 | 64 | 1.2 GB/s | 62.7 | 5 | Poor avalanche properties |
| Blake2 | 256 | 1.1 GB/s | 5.1 | 10 | Cryptographic |
| SHA1 | 160 | 0.8 GB/s | 5.6 | 10 | Cryptographic but broken |
| MD5 | 128 | 0.6 GB/s | 7.8 | 10 | Cryptographic but broken |

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method where you can select what file types to hash within a path recursively:

```
import pathlib
import hashlib

def getHashForFileTypesInPath(path, listFileTypes):
    print(f"Generating hash for files matching {listFileTypes} in path {path}")
    # Get list of all paths that mach types in path recursively
    matchedPaths = []
    for f in listFileTypes:
        matchedPaths.extend(list(path.rglob(f)))
    matchedPaths.sort()
    
    # Get hash of each matched file. 
    # Keep updating hash object with each file's hash to ultimately get a
    #     single combined hash for all files in path
    # If any file's hash changes, overall combined hash will change.
    m = hashlib.sha1()
    for p in matchedPaths:
        digest = hashlib.file_digest(open(p, 'rb'), 'sha1')
        m.update(digest.digest())
    hashSha1 = m.hexdigest()
    return hashSha1


path = pathlib.Path(r"C:\temp\temp")
# listFileTypes = ['*.jpg', '*.pdf'] # Can provide a list of types
listFileTypes = ['*.*'] # Can hash every type
hashSha1 = getHashForFileTypesInPath(path, listFileTypes)
print(f"hash: {hashSha1}")
```

Output:

```
Generating hash for files matching ['*.*'] in path C:\temp\temp
hash: 621714d8751c2f7471cd81cc664c98299ba50ec2
```