# Removing Airflow task logs

Tags: airflow

I'm running 5 DAG's which have generated a total of about 6GB of log data in the `base_log_folder` over a months period. I just added a `remote_base_log_folder` but it seems it does not exclude logging to the `base_log_folder`.

Is there anyway to automatically remove old log files, rotate them or force airflow to not log on disk (base_log_folder) only in remote storage?

Comment: I would be curious 2 years later what your solution was... experiencing this issue

Comment: I am also curious 5 years later what your solution was. I am experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 30):

Please refer https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-maintenance-dags

This plugin has DAGs that can kill halted tasks and log-cleanups.
You can grab the concepts and can come up with a new DAG that can cleanup as per your requirement.

Comment: This one specifically worked great for me. Took about 10 minutes to get working - very configurable and super simple: https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-maintenance-dags/tree/master/log-cleanup

Answer (score 15):

We remove the Task logs by implementing our own `FileTaskHandler`, and then pointing to it in the `airflow.cfg`. So, we overwrite the default LogHandler to keep only N task logs, without scheduling additional DAGs.

We are using `Airflow==1.10.1`.

```
[core]
logging_config_class = log_config.LOGGING_CONFIG
```

**log_config.LOGGING_CONFIG**

```
BASE_LOG_FOLDER = conf.get('core', 'BASE_LOG_FOLDER')
FOLDER_TASK_TEMPLATE = '{{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}'
FILENAME_TEMPLATE = '{{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ ts }}/{{ try_number }}.log'

LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    'formatters': {},
    'handlers': {
        '...': {},
        'task': {
            'class': 'file_task_handler.FileTaskRotationHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow.job',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
            'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
            'folder_task_template': FOLDER_TASK_TEMPLATE,
            'retention': 20
        },
        '...': {}
    },
    'loggers': {
        'airflow.task': {
            'handlers': ['task'],
            'level': JOB_LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'airflow.task_runner': {
            'handlers': ['task'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
        },
        '...': {}
    }
}
```

**file_task_handler.FileTaskRotationHandler**

```
import os
import shutil

from airflow.utils.helpers import parse_template_string
from airflow.utils.log.file_task_handler import FileTaskHandler


class FileTaskRotationHandler(FileTaskHandler):

    def __init__(self, base_log_folder, filename_template, folder_task_template, retention):
        """
        :param base_log_folder: Base log folder to place logs.
        :param filename_template: template filename string.
        :param folder_task_template: template folder task path.
        :param retention: Number of folder logs to keep
        """
        super(FileTaskRotationHandler, self).__init__(base_log_folder, filename_template)
        self.retention = retention
        self.folder_task_template, self.folder_task_template_jinja_template = \
            parse_template_string(folder_task_template)

    @staticmethod
    def _get_directories(path='.'):
        return next(os.walk(path))[1]

    def _render_folder_task_path(self, ti):
        if self.folder_task_template_jinja_template:
            jinja_context = ti.get_template_context()
            return self.folder_task_template_jinja_template.render(**jinja_context)

        return self.folder_task_template.format(dag_id=ti.dag_id, task_id=ti.task_id)

    def _init_file(self, ti):
        relative_path = self._render_folder_task_path(ti)
        folder_task_path = os.path.join(self.local_base, relative_path)
        subfolders = self._get_directories(folder_task_path)
        to_remove = set(subfolders) - set(subfolders[-self.retention:])

        for dir_to_remove in to_remove:
            full_dir_to_remove = os.path.join(folder_task_path, dir_to_remove)
            print('Removing', full_dir_to_remove)
            shutil.rmtree(full_dir_to_remove)

        return FileTaskHandler._init_file(self, ti)
```

Comment: This only helps remove local log files, but doesn't do remote logging.

Comment: This is the most comprehensive solution available even today. The only thing, it does not guarantee that only old folders will be removed. Since os.walk() does not ensure order. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282370/in-what-order-does-os-walk-iterates-iterate

Comment: where was log_config ?

Answer (score 6):

Airflow maintainers don't think truncating logs is a part of airflow core logic, to see [this](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2442), and then in this issue, maintainers suggest to change LOG_LEVEL avoid too many log data.

And in [this](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2191) PR, we can learn how to change log level in `airflow.cfg`.

good luck.

Comment: That's because airflow maintainers are lazy

Answer (score 3):

I know it sounds savage, but have you tried pointing `base_log_folder` to `/dev/null`? I use Airflow as a part of a container, so I don't care about the files either, as long as the logger pipe to `STDOUT` as well.

Not sure how well this plays with S3 though.

Comment: don't think this works as gives NotADirectoryError with message `NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/dev/null/dag_id=`

Answer (score 3):

Usually apache airflow grab the disk space due to 3 reasons

- **1. airflow scheduler logs files
  2. mysql binaly logs [Major]
  3. xcom table records.**

To make it clean up on regular basis I have set up a dag which run on daily basis and cleans the binary logs and truncate the xcom table to make the disk space free
You also might need to install [pip install mysql-connector-python].
To clean up scheduler log files I do delete them manually two times in a week to avoid the risk of logs deleted which needs to be required for some reasons.

I clean the logs files by [sudo rm -rd airflow/logs/] command.

Below is my python code for reference

```
'
"""Example DAG demonstrating the usage of the PythonOperator."""

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator


args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'email_on_failure':True,
    'retries': 1,
    'email':['Your Email Id'],
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}


dag = DAG(
    dag_id='airflow_logs_cleanup',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    start_date=days_ago(0),
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
    tags=['airflow_maintenance'],
)

def truncate_table():
    import mysql.connector

    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='db_name',
                                         user='username',
                                         password='your password',
                                         auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql_select_query = """TRUNCATE TABLE xcom"""
    cursor.execute(sql_select_query)
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
    print("XCOM Table truncated successfully")


def delete_binary_logs():
    import mysql.connector
    from datetime import datetime
    date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='db_name',
                                         user='username',
                                         password='your_password',
                                         auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = 'PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE ' + "'" + str(date) + "'"

    sql_select_query = query
    cursor.execute(sql_select_query)
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
    print("Binary logs deleted  successfully")

t1 = PythonOperator(

    task_id='truncate_table',
    python_callable=truncate_table, dag=dag

)

t2 = PythonOperator(

    task_id='delete_binary_logs',
    python_callable=delete_binary_logs, dag=dag
)
t2 << t1
```

'

Answer (score 1):

For your concrete problems, I have some suggestions.
For those, you would always need a specialized logging config as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54195537/2668430

- > automatically remove old log files and rotate them

I don't have any practical experience with the `TimedRotatingFileHandler` from the Python standard library yet, but you might give it a try:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler

It not only offers to rotate your files based on a time interval, but if you specify the `backupCount` parameter, it even deletes your old log files:

> If `backupCount` is nonzero, at most `backupCount` files will be kept, and if more would be created when rollover occurs, the oldest one is deleted. The deletion logic uses the interval to determine which files to delete, so changing the interval may leave old files lying around.

Which sounds pretty much like the best solution for your first problem.

---

- > force airflow to not log on disk (base_log_folder), but only in remote storage?

In this case you should specify the logging config in such a way that you do *not* have any logging handlers that write to a file, i.e. remove all `FileHandlers`.

Rather, try to find logging handlers that send the output directly to a remote address.
E.g. [CMRESHandler](https://github.com/cmanaha/python-elasticsearch-logger) which logs directly to ElasticSearch but needs some extra fields in the log calls.
Alternatively, write your own handler class and let it inherit from the Python standard library's [HTTPHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#httphandler).

---

A final suggestion would be to combine both the `TimedRotatingFileHandler` and setup ElasticSearch together with FileBeat, so you would be able to store your logs inside ElasticSearch (i.e. remote), but you wouldn't store a huge amount of logs on your Airflow disk since they will be removed by the `backupCount` retention policy of your `TimedRotatingFileHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprized but it worked for me. Update your config as below:

```
base_log_folder=""
```

It is test in minio and in s3.

Answer (score 0):

Our solution looks a lot like Franzi's:

Running on Airflow 2.0.1 (py3.8)

**Override default logging configuration**

Since we use a helm chart for airflow deployment it was easiest to push an env there, but it can also be done in the airflow.cfg or using ENV in dockerfile.

```
# Set custom logging configuration to enable log rotation for task logging
AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_CONFIG_CLASS: "airflow_plugins.settings.airflow_local_settings.DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG"
```

Then we added the logging configuration together with the custom log handler to a python module we build and install in the docker image. As described here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html

**Logging configuration snippet**

This is only a copy on the default from the airflow codebase, but then the task logger gets a different handler.

```
DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG: Dict[str, Any] = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'airflow': {'format': LOG_FORMAT},
    'airflow_coloured': {
        'format': COLORED_LOG_FORMAT if COLORED_LOG else LOG_FORMAT,
        'class': COLORED_FORMATTER_CLASS if COLORED_LOG else 'logging.Formatter',
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'class': 'airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin.RedirectStdHandler',
        'formatter': 'airflow_coloured',
        'stream': 'sys.stdout',
    },
    'task': {
        'class': 'airflow_plugins.log.rotating_file_task_handler.RotatingFileTaskHandler',
        'formatter': 'airflow',
        'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
        'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        'maxBytes': 10485760,  # 10MB
        'backupCount': 6,
    },
    ...
```

**RotatingFileTaskHandler**

And finally the custom handler which is just a merge of the logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler and the FileTaskHandler.

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
"""File logging handler for tasks."""
import logging
import os
from pathlib import Path
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Optional

import requests

from airflow.configuration import AirflowConfigException, conf
from airflow.utils.helpers import parse_template_string

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from airflow.models import TaskInstance


class RotatingFileTaskHandler(logging.Handler):
    """
    FileTaskHandler is a python log handler that handles and reads
    task instance logs. It creates and delegates log handling
    to `logging.FileHandler` after receiving task instance context.
    It reads logs from task instance's host machine.

    :param base_log_folder: Base log folder to place logs.
    :param filename_template: template filename string
    """

    def __init__(self, base_log_folder: str, filename_template: str, maxBytes=0, backupCount=0):
        self.max_bytes = maxBytes
        self.backup_count = backupCount
        super().__init__()
        self.handler = None  # type: Optional[logging.FileHandler]
        self.local_base = base_log_folder
        self.filename_template, self.filename_jinja_template = parse_template_string(filename_template)

    def set_context(self, ti: "TaskInstance"):
        """
        Provide task_instance context to airflow task handler.

        :param ti: task instance object
        """
        local_loc = self._init_file(ti)
        self.handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
            filename=local_loc,
            mode='a',
            maxBytes=self.max_bytes,
            backupCount=self.backup_count,
            encoding='utf-8',
            delay=False,
        )
        if self.formatter:
            self.handler.setFormatter(self.formatter)
        self.handler.setLevel(self.level)

    def emit(self, record):
        if self.handler:
            self.handler.emit(record)

    def flush(self):
        if self.handler:
            self.handler.flush()

    def close(self):
        if self.handler:
            self.handler.close()

    def _render_filename(self, ti, try_number):
        if self.filename_jinja_template:
            if hasattr(ti, 'task'):
                jinja_context = ti.get_template_context()
                jinja_context['try_number'] = try_number
            else:
                jinja_context = {
                    'ti': ti,
                    'ts': ti.execution_date.isoformat(),
                    'try_number': try_number,
                }
            return self.filename_jinja_template.render(**jinja_context)

        return self.filename_template.format(
            dag_id=ti.dag_id,
            task_id=ti.task_id,
            execution_date=ti.execution_date.isoformat(),
            try_number=try_number,
        )

    def _read_grouped_logs(self):
        return False

    def _read(self, ti, try_number, metadata=None):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        """
        Template method that contains custom logic of reading
        logs given the try_number.

        :param ti: task instance record
        :param try_number: current try_number to read log from
        :param metadata: log metadata,
                         can be used for steaming log reading and auto-tailing.
        :return: log message as a string and metadata.
        """
        # Task instance here might be different from task instance when
        # initializing the handler. Thus explicitly getting log location
        # is needed to get correct log path.
        log_relative_path = self._render_filename(ti, try_number)
        location = os.path.join(self.local_base, log_relative_path)

        log = ""

        if os.path.exists(location):
            try:
                with open(location) as file:
                    log += f"*** Reading local file: {location}\n"
                    log += "".join(file.readlines())
            except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
                log = f"*** Failed to load local log file: {location}\n"
                log += "*** {}\n".format(str(e))
        elif conf.get('core', 'executor') == 'KubernetesExecutor':  # pylint: disable=too-many-nested-blocks
            try:
                from airflow.kubernetes.kube_client import get_kube_client

                kube_client = get_kube_client()

                if len(ti.hostname) >= 63:
                    # Kubernetes takes the pod name and truncates it for the hostname. This truncated hostname
                    # is returned for the fqdn to comply with the 63 character limit imposed by DNS standards
                    # on any label of a FQDN.
                    pod_list = kube_client.list_namespaced_pod(conf.get('kubernetes', 'namespace'))
                    matches = [
                        pod.metadata.name
                        for pod in pod_list.items
                        if pod.metadata.name.startswith(ti.hostname)
                    ]
                    if len(matches) == 1:
                        if len(matches[0]) > len(ti.hostname):
                            ti.hostname = matches[0]

                log += '*** Trying to get logs (last 100 lines) from worker pod {} ***\n\n'.format(
                    ti.hostname
                )

                res = kube_client.read_namespaced_pod_log(
                    name=ti.hostname,
                    namespace=conf.get('kubernetes', 'namespace'),
                    container='base',
                    follow=False,
                    tail_lines=100,
                    _preload_content=False,
                )

                for line in res:
                    log += line.decode()

            except Exception as f:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
                log += '*** Unable to fetch logs from worker pod {} ***\n{}\n\n'.format(ti.hostname, str(f))
        else:
            url = os.path.join("http://{ti.hostname}:{worker_log_server_port}/log", log_relative_path).format(
                ti=ti, worker_log_server_port=conf.get('celery', 'WORKER_LOG_SERVER_PORT')
            )
            log += f"*** Log file does not exist: {location}\n"
            log += f"*** Fetching from: {url}\n"
            try:
                timeout = None  # No timeout
                try:
                    timeout = conf.getint('webserver', 'log_fetch_timeout_sec')
                except (AirflowConfigException, ValueError):
                    pass

                response = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
                response.encoding = "utf-8"

                # Check if the resource was properly fetched
                response.raise_for_status()

                log += '\n' + response.text
            except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
                log += "*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. {}\n".format(str(e))

        return log, {'end_of_log': True}

    def read(self, task_instance, try_number=None, metadata=None):
        """
        Read logs of given task instance from local machine.

        :param task_instance: task instance object
        :param try_number: task instance try_number to read logs from. If None
                           it returns all logs separated by try_number
        :param metadata: log metadata,
                         can be used for steaming log reading and auto-tailing.
        :return: a list of listed tuples which order log string by host
        """
        # Task instance increments its try number when it starts to run.
        # So the log for a particular task try will only show up when
        # try number gets incremented in DB, i.e logs produced the time
        # after cli run and before try_number + 1 in DB will not be displayed.

        if try_number is None:
            next_try = task_instance.next_try_number
            try_numbers = list(range(1, next_try))
        elif try_number < 1:
            logs = [
                [('default_host', f'Error fetching the logs. Try number {try_number} is invalid.')],
            ]
            return logs, [{'end_of_log': True}]
        else:
            try_numbers = [try_number]

        logs = [''] * len(try_numbers)
        metadata_array = [{}] * len(try_numbers)
        for i, try_number_element in enumerate(try_numbers):
            log, metadata = self._read(task_instance, try_number_element, metadata)
            # es_task_handler return logs grouped by host. wrap other handler returning log string
            # with default/ empty host so that UI can render the response in the same way
            logs[i] = log if self._read_grouped_logs() else [(task_instance.hostname, log)]
            metadata_array[i] = metadata

        return logs, metadata_array

    def _init_file(self, ti):
        """
        Create log directory and give it correct permissions.

        :param ti: task instance object
        :return: relative log path of the given task instance
        """
        # To handle log writing when tasks are impersonated, the log files need to
        # be writable by the user that runs the Airflow command and the user
        # that is impersonated. This is mainly to handle corner cases with the
        # SubDagOperator. When the SubDagOperator is run, all of the operators
        # run under the impersonated user and create appropriate log files
        # as the impersonated user. However, if the user manually runs tasks
        # of the SubDagOperator through the UI, then the log files are created
        # by the user that runs the Airflow command. For example, the Airflow
        # run command may be run by the `airflow_sudoable` user, but the Airflow
        # tasks may be run by the `airflow` user. If the log files are not
        # writable by both users, then it's possible that re-running a task
        # via the UI (or vice versa) results in a permission error as the task
        # tries to write to a log file created by the other user.
        relative_path = self._render_filename(ti, ti.try_number)
        full_path = os.path.join(self.local_base, relative_path)
        directory = os.path.dirname(full_path)
        # Create the log file and give it group writable permissions
        # TODO(aoen): Make log dirs and logs globally readable for now since the SubDag
        # operator is not compatible with impersonation (e.g. if a Celery executor is used
        # for a SubDag operator and the SubDag operator has a different owner than the
        # parent DAG)
        Path(directory).mkdir(mode=0o777, parents=True, exist_ok=True)

        if not os.path.exists(full_path):
            open(full_path, "a").close()
            # TODO: Investigate using 444 instead of 666.
            os.chmod(full_path, 0o666)

        return full_path
```

Maybe a final note; the links in the airflow UI to the logging will now only open the latest logfile, not the older rotated files which are only accessible by means of SSH or any other interface to access the airflow logging path.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that there is a rotation mechanism but you can store them in S3 or google cloud storage as describe here : https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/configuration.html#logs

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the remote logging option with `remote_base_log_folder` storing the log files on GCS. This adds the logs to GCS but does not remove them locally. I guess I was wondering how other people are dealing with large amount of log files filling up their disks in production.

Comment: @jompa did u find a solution? I am also storing logs at S3 but how do I remove local logs?