# Remove Airflow Scheduler logs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, docker-volume, airflow-scheduler

I am using Docker Apache airflow VERSION 1.9.0-2 (https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow).

The scheduler produces a significant amount of logs, and the filesystem will quickly run out of space, so I am trying to programmatically delete the scheduler logs created by airflow, found in the scheduler container in (/usr/local/airflow/logs/scheduler)

I have all of these maintenance tasks set up:
https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-maintenance-dags

However, these tasks only delete logs on the worker, and the scheduler logs are in the scheduler container.

I have also setup remote logging, sending logs to S3, but as mentioned in this SO post [Removing Airflow task logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43548744/removing-airflow-task-logs) this setup does not stop airflow from writing to the local machine.

Additionally, I have also tried creating a shared named volume between the worker and the scheduler, as outlined here [Docker Compose - Share named volume between multiple containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284484/docker-compose-share-named-volume-between-multiple-containers).  However, I get the following error in worker:

`ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file.processor': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/airflow/logs/scheduler'`

and the following error in scheduler:

`ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file.processor': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/airflow/logs/scheduler/2018-04-11'`

**And so, how do people delete scheduler logs??**

Answer (score 12):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46197914/4245534) reply, I have added the `airflow-log-cleanup.py` DAG (with some changes to its parameters) from [here](https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-maintenance-dags/tree/master/log-cleanup) to remove **all** old airflow logs, including scheduler logs.

My changes are minor except that given my EC2's disk size (7.7G for `/dev/xvda1`), 30 days default value for `DEFAULT_MAX_LOG_AGE_IN_DAYS` seemed too large so (I had 4 DAGs) I changed it to 14 days, but feel free to adjust it according to your environment:

`DEFAULT_MAX_LOG_AGE_IN_DAYS = Variable.get("max_log_age_in_days", 30)` changed to 
`DEFAULT_MAX_LOG_AGE_IN_DAYS = Variable.get("max_log_age_in_days", 14)`

Answer (score 4):

Following could be one option to resolve this issue.

Login to the docker container using following mechanism

```
#>docker exec -it <name-or-id-of-container> sh
```

While running above command make sure - container is running.

and then use cron jobs to configure scheduled rm command on those log files.

Comment: Ref for cron job: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Comment: Ha, I was actually thinking about something like that last night... I think i'm just reluctant to have a cron job clean up after my scheduler lol... I think there could also be a solution with sharing folders between containers, but I lack docker and airflow knowledge. Thank you for suggestion!

Comment: I ended up adding this `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose exec -T scheduler bash -c "rm -rf /usr/local/airflow/logs/scheduler/*"` and running it with the following cron expression `0 0 * * * cd /path/to/script && /bin/bash ./cleanup.sh 1> /tmp/success.txt 2> /tmp/err.txt`

Answer (score 4):

[This answer to "Removing Airflow Task logs"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54195537/1956944) also fits your use case in Airflow 1.10.

Basically, you need to implement a custom log handler and configure Airflow logging to use that handler instead of the default (See `UPDATING.md`, **not** `README` nor docs!!, in Airflow source repo)

One word of caution: Due to the way logging, multiprocessing, and Airflow default handlers interact, it is safer to override handler methods than to extend them by calling super() in a derived handler class. Because Airflow default handlers don't use locks

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time trying to add "maintenance" DAGs that would clear logs generated by the different airflow components started as **Docker containers**.

The problem was in fact more at the Docker level, each one of those processes are responsible of tons of logs that are, by default, stored in `json` files by Docker. The solution was to change the [logging drivers](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#supported-logging-drivers) so that logs are not stored on the Docker hosting instance anymore; but sent directly to AWS CloudWatch Logs in my case.

I just had to add the following to each service in the `docker-compose.yml` file (https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) :

```yaml
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: myAWSLogsGroupID
```

Note that the EC2 instance on which my "docker-composed" Airflow app is running has an AWS role that allows her to create a log stream and add log events (`CreateLogStream` and `PutLogEvents` actions in AWS IAM service).

If you run it on a machine outside of the AWS ecosystem, you'd need to ensure it has [access to AWS through credentials](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/#credentials).

Comment: Actually you can rotate docker logs easily. So no, this is not caused by docker, and your solution will not help the scheduler log issue at all.