# Disable Airflow logs in local DAGs folder

Tags: logging, amazon-ec2, airflow

I’m running Airflow 2.0.1 on EC2 and enabled the s3 logging. I want to disable the logs that are being created in the local (EC2) server.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local logging is needed for airflow, since it writes to local and after the task completes it sends to remote.

This is specified in their documentation: "In the Airflow Web UI, remote logs take precedence over local logs when remote logging is enabled. If remote logs can not be found or accessed, local logs will be displayed. Note that logs are only sent to remote storage once a task is complete (including failure); In other words, remote logs for running tasks are unavailable (but local logs are available)."

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/logging-monitoring/logging-tasks.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to post duplicate answer.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68389590/8374579) may address your question.