# Reading files from a folder using python

Tags: python

I am trying to read all files within a directory.

```
for root, dirs,files in os.walk(path):
        for j in files:
            print(str(j))
```

This is my code where `path` is the path of the directory to be read.But it does not print the files in the order of their names. In my case, I have files from `0.txt`,`1.txt`,.... to `3590.txt`. I want it to print the files in the same order. But rather it starts from `579.txt` . How can I fix this? I want to do some computation on the files in the same order and so just storing the names in a list and sorting it wont help.

Comment: _"I want to do some computation on the files in the same order and so just storing the names in a list and sorting it wont help."_ You can use a list and still perform computations on its contents. Can you explain further why this wouldn't work?

Comment: Related to [Nonalphanumeric list order from os.listdir() in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813061/nonalphanumeric-list-order-from-os-listdir-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about sorting them with a lambda to use the int in the filename:

```
for root, dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    for j in sorted(files, key=lambda key: int(key.replace(".txt", ""))):
        print(str(j))
```

Comment: This won't sort them numerically, though. For example, `sorted(["2.txt", "11.txt", "300.txt"])` gives `['11.txt', '2.txt', '300.txt']`. (this may actually be what the OP means by "sorting won't help")

Comment: No it is not working as Kevin said. I am getting something like this-539.txt
54.txt
540.txt
541.txt

Comment: If lexicographic sorting was really the problem though, I wouldn't expect to see "539.txt" first, since "1.txt" and "0.txt" still precede it alphabetically.

Comment: @Kevin Yes `0.txt` and `1.txt` appear before `539` . I just posted three files where it is failing.In actual output,`0` and `1` appear before `539`

Comment: If you want the sorting to be in numerical order rather than lexicographic, you could use the natsort library. `from natsort import natsorted` then replace `sorted` in the above code with `natsorted`.

Answer (score 0):

As **file name structure** is like `$Number$.txt`, so we can sort by Number.

**Demo**:

```
>>> l = ["0.txt", "1.txt", "33.txt", "2.txt", "10.txt", "11.txt"]
>>> sorted([(int(i.replace(".txt", "")), i) for i in l ])
[(0, '0.txt'), (1, '1.txt'), (2, '2.txt'), (10, '10.txt'), (11, '11.txt'), (33, '33.txt')]
>>> [i[1] for i in sorted([(int(i.replace(".txt", "")), i) for i in l ])]
['0.txt', '1.txt', '2.txt', '10.txt', '11.txt', '33.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try sorting them by using natsort:

```py
import natsort
unsorted_files = ['2.txt','3.txt','1.txt']
sorted_files = natsort.natsorted(unsorted_files)
print(sorted_files)
```

you need to install the package if not installed by using :

```
pip install natsort
```