# Order of filenames from os.listdir

Tags: python

Assume that folder A contains the following files:

```
0.jpg
1.jpg
2.jpg
.
.
.
n.jpg
.
.
.
```

Now, a python script looks into folder A and using

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(path_to_A):
    for filename in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
```

reads the `filename` (reads each image) and updates an array B.
The size of array B is exactly that of the number of images inside A.

My question is, will it ALWAYS be the case that the j-th position of the array will correspond to the j.jpg image file?

For example if the names inside folder A differ ( but are sorted in the lexicographic order - btw, is it really the lexicographic order that is preserved when we list a directory in win or linux OS? ) will this be depicted in array B?

Thanks!

Comment: why would you risk it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the j-th position will (or at least CAN) vary. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) (emphasis mine)

> `os.listdir(path='.')`
>   Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path. **The list is in arbitrary order**, and does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.

That said, if you want it sorted, `sorted` produces a stable lexicographically sorted list. `sorted(os.listdir("your/path/here"))[n]` should always point to the n-th file (unless your directory changes contents!)

Comment: `sorted` will be lexically stable, but keep in mind that it's case sensitive. So `A.jpg` and `a.jpg` will be nowhere near each other, and `C.jpg` will show up before `b.jpg`. There's also issues like `1.jpg` vs. `02.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

Original Author: [Elliot's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203146/elliot) on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813061/non-alphanumeric-list-order-from-os-listdir/51968169#51968169)

**Use natsort library:**

Install the library with the following command for Ubuntu and other Debian versions

**Python 2**

```
sudo pip install natsort
```

**Python 3**

```
sudo pip3 install natsort
```

Details of how to use this library is found [here](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/)