# Tensorflow: loss resets after successfully restored checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow, reset, restore, checkpoint, loss

There are no errors when saving or restoring. The weights appear to have restored correctly.

I am trying to build my own minimal character level RNN by following [karpathy/min-char-rnn.py](https://gist.github.com/karpathy/d4dee566867f8291f086), [sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow](https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow), and the [Tensorflow RNN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent/). My script seems to work as expected except when I try to restore / resume training.

If I restart the script and restore from checkpoint and then resume training, the loss would always go back up as if there are no checkpoints (despite the weights having restored correctly). 
However, within the script's execution, if I reset the graph, start a new session, and restore, then I am able to continue minimizing the loss as expected.

I have tried to run this on my desktop (with GPU) and laptop (CPU only), both on Windows with Tensorflow 0.12.

Below is my code, and I have uploaded the code + data + console output here: 
https://gist.github.com/dk1027/777c3da7ba1ff7739b5f5e89491bef73

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn_cell

class model_input:

    def __init__(self,data_path, batch_size, steps):
        self.batch_idx = 0
        self.data_path = data_path
        self.steps = steps
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        data = open(self.data_path).read()
        data_size = len(data)
        self.vocab = set(data)
        self.vocab_size = len(self.vocab)
        self.vocab_to_idx = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(self.vocab)}
        self.idx_to_vocab = {i:v for i,v in enumerate(self.vocab)}
        c = self.batch_size * self.steps
        #Offset by 1 character because we want to predict the next character
        _data_as_idx = np.asarray([self.vocab_to_idx[v] for v in data], dtype=np.int32)
        self.X = _data_as_idx[:-1]
        self.Y = _data_as_idx[1:]

    def reset(self):
        self.batch_idx = 0

    def next_batch2(self):
        i = self.batch_idx
        j = self.batch_idx + self.batch_size * self.steps

        if j >= self.X.shape[0]:
            i = 0
            j = self.batch_size * self.steps
            self.batch_idx = 0

        #print("next_batch: (%s,%s)" %(i,j))
        x = self.X[i:j]
        x = x.reshape(-1,self.steps)

        _xlen = x.shape[0]
        _y = self.Y[i:j]
        _y = _y.reshape(-1,self.steps)
        self.batch_idx += 1

        return x, _y

    def toIdx(self, s):
        res = []
        for _s in s:
            res.append(self.vocab_to_idx[_s])
        return res

    def toStr(self, idx):
        s = ''
        for i in idx:
            s += self.idx_to_vocab[i]
        return s

class Config():
    def __init__(self):
        # Parameters
        self.learning_rate = 0.001
        self.training_iters = 10000
        self.batch_size = 20
        self.display_step = 200
        self.max_epoch = 1
        # Network Parameters
        self.n_input = 1 # 1 character input
        self.n_steps = 25 # sequence length
        self.n_hidden = 128 # hidden layer num of features
        self.n_rnn_layers = 2
        # To be set later
        self.vocab_size = None

# Train
def Train(sess, model, data, config, saver):
    init_state = sess.run(model.initial_state)
    data.reset()
    epoch = 0
    while epoch < config.max_epoch:
        # Keep training until reach max iterations
        step = 0
        while step * config.batch_size < config.training_iters:
            # Run optimization op (backprop)
            fetch_dict = {
                "cost": model.cost,
                "final_state": model.final_state,
                "op" : model.train_op
            }
            feed_dict = {}
            for i, (c, h) in enumerate(model.initial_state):
                feed_dict[c] = init_state[i].c
                feed_dict[h] = init_state[i].h
            batch_x, batch_y = data.next_batch2()
            feed_dict[model.x]=batch_x
            feed_dict[model.y]=batch_y
            fetches = sess.run(fetch_dict, feed_dict=feed_dict)

            if (step % config.display_step) == 0:
                print("Iter " + str(step*config.batch_size) + ", Minibatch Loss={:.7f}".format(fetches["cost"]))
            step += 1
            if (step*config.batch_size % 5000) == 0:
                sp = saver.save(sess, config.save_path + "model.ckpt", global_step = step * config.batch_size + epoch * config.training_iters)
                print("Saved to %s" % sp)
        sp = saver.save(sess, config.save_path + "model.ckpt", global_step = step * config.batch_size + epoch * config.training_iters)
        print("Saved to %s" % sp)
        epoch += 1

    print("Optimization Finished!")


class Model():
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config

        lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(config.n_hidden, state_is_tuple=True)

        self.cell = rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell] * config.n_rnn_layers, state_is_tuple=True)

        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [config.batch_size, config.n_steps])
        self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [config.batch_size, config.n_steps]) 
        self.initial_state = self.cell.zero_state(config.batch_size, tf.float32)

        with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
            embedding = tf.get_variable("embedding", [config.vocab_size, config.n_hidden], dtype=tf.float32)
            inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, self.x)
        outputs = []
        state = self.initial_state
        with tf.variable_scope('rnn'):
            softmax_w = tf.get_variable("softmax_w", [config.n_hidden, config.vocab_size])
            softmax_b = tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [config.vocab_size])

            for time_step in range(config.n_steps):
                if time_step > 0: tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
                (cell_output, state) = self.cell(inputs[:, time_step, :], state)
                outputs.append(cell_output)

        output = tf.reshape(tf.concat(1, outputs), [-1, config.n_hidden])
        self.logits = tf.matmul(output, softmax_w) + softmax_b
        loss = tf.nn.seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example(
            [self.logits],
            [self.y],
            [tf.ones([config.batch_size * config.n_steps], dtype=tf.float32)],
            name="seq2seq")

        self.cost = tf.reduce_sum(loss) / config.batch_size
        self.final_state = state

        tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
        grads, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(self.cost, tvars),5)
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(config.learning_rate)
        self.train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, tvars))

def main():
    # Read input data
    data_path = "1sonnet.txt"
    save_path = "./save/"

    config = Config()
    data = model_input(data_path, config.batch_size, config.n_steps)
    config.vocab_size = data.vocab_size
    config.data_path = data_path
    config.save_path = save_path

    train_model = Model(config)
    print("Model defined.")

    bReproProblem = True
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(save_path)
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
            print("restored from %s" % ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)

        Train(sess, train_model, data, config, saver)


    if bReproProblem:
        tf.reset_default_graph() #reset everything
        data.reset()
        train_model2 = Model(config)
        print("Starting a new session, restore from checkpoint, and train again")
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            saver2 = tf.train.Saver()
            ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(save_path)
            if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
                saver2.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
                print("restored from %s" % ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)

            Train(sess, train_model2, data, config, saver2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Please make sure your label is **same** each time you run your code, especially for those who use list indices as labels.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646266/tensorflow-loss-jumps-up-after-restoring-rnn-net) for details.

If you use list indices as labels, sort data or save indices to disks. Use:

```
labels = sorted(set(data))
```

instead of

```
labels = set(data))
```

### General advice

In Python implementation, there are some methods, like `set()` or `os.listdir()`, return a collection which is not sorted. In other words, the index of an item might be different at each run.

For `set()`, Python [use a random method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646266/tensorflow-loss-jumps-up-after-restoring-rnn-net) to build a `set`. For `os.listdir()`, [it doesn't promise the order of the returned list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813061/non-alphanumeric-list-order-from-os-listdir). So for a robust code, use `sorted()` to your dataset is recommended.

### For your question

```
data_size = len(data)
self.vocab = set(data)
self.vocab_size = len(self.vocab)
self.vocab_to_idx = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(self.vocab)}
self.idx_to_vocab = {i:v for i,v in enumerate(self.vocab)}
```

It might be caused by the way you build your label. `vocab_to_idx` might be different each time you run your code.

Just add a `sorted()`:

```
data_size = len(data)
self.vocab = sorted(set(data))
self.vocab_size = len(self.vocab)
self.vocab_to_idx = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(self.vocab)}
self.idx_to_vocab = {i:v for i,v in enumerate(self.vocab)}
```