# Sort string list by a number in string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, sorting

I have the following string list. Then, I want to sort it by a number in each element. `sorted` failed because it cannot handle the order such as between `10` and `3`. I can imagine if I use `re`, I can do it. But it is not interesting. Do you guys have nice implementation ideas? I suppose python 3.x for this code.

```
names = [
'Test-1.model',
'Test-4.model',
'Test-6.model',
'Test-8.model',
'Test-10.model',
'Test-20.model'
]
number_sorted = get_number_sorted(names)
print(number_sorted)
'Test-20.model'
'Test-10.model'
'Test-8.model'
'Test-6.model'
'Test-4.model'
'Test-1.model'
```

Answer (score 7):

the key is ... the key

```
sorted(names, key=lambda x: int(x.partition('-')[2].partition('.')[0]))
```

Getting that part of the string recognized as the sort order by separating it out and transforming it to an int.

Answer (score 5):

Some alternatives:

(1) Slicing by position:

```
sorted(names, key=lambda x: int(x[5:-6]))
```

(2) Stripping substrings:

```
sorted(names, key=lambda x: int(x.replace('Test-', '').replace('.model', '')))
```

Or [better](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix) (Pandas version >3.9):

```
x.removeprefix('Test-').removesuffix('.model')
```

(3) Splitting characters (also possible via str.partition):

```
sorted(names, key=lambda x: int(x.split('-')[1].split('.')[0]))
```

(4) Map with np.argsort on any of (1)-(3):

```
list(map(names.__getitem__, np.argsort([int(x[5:-6]) for x in names])))
```

Comment: Given the goal is to sort the original strings, not just get the sorted numbers, using a `key` function to perform the transform would make more sense (and avoid an unnecessary genexpr), e.g. for your first example, `sorted(names, key=lambda x: int(x[5:-6]))`, or for your second `sorted(names, key=lambda x: int(x.replace('Test-', '').replace('.model', '')))`

Comment: @ShadowRanger, yep I realise this now. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I like the multiple options now.  That is innovative.

Comment: Since 3.9, `x.removeprefix('Test-').removesuffix('.model')` might be more appropriate than the `.replace` version. [Doc for str.removeprefix and str.removesuffix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix)

Answer (score 3):

I found a similar question and a solution by myself.
[Nonalphanumeric list order from os.listdir() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813061/nonalphanumeric-list-order-from-os-listdir-in-python)

```
import re
def sorted_alphanumeric(data):
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ] 
    return sorted(data, key=alphanum_key, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.findall` in with the `key` of the sort function:

```
import re
names = [
 'Test-1.model',
 'Test-4.model',
 'Test-6.model',
 'Test-8.model',
 'Test-10.model',
 'Test-20.model'
]
final_data = sorted(names, key=lambda x:int(re.findall('(?<=Test-)\d+', x)[0]), reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
['Test-20.model', 'Test-10.model', 'Test-8.model', 'Test-6.model', 'Test-4.model', 'Test-1.model']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex based approach.  We can extract the test number from the string, cast to int, and then sort by that.

```
import re

def grp(txt): 
    s = re.search(r'Test-(\d+)\.model', txt, re.IGNORECASE)
    if s:
        return int(s.group(1))
    else:
        return float('-inf')  # Sorts non-matching strings ahead of matching strings

names.sort(key=grp)
```

Comment: This still sorts string style (lexicographically), not numerically. You'd want to return `int(s.group(1))` in the first case, and some filler numerical value (e.g. `float('-inf')` to sort put strings not matching the pattern at the front of the resulting `list`), not `str`, in the `else` case.

Comment: @ShadowRanger No, even [making those changes](http://rextester.com/TKKP68517) still doesn't fix it.  I don't know Python, by the way.  Feel free to edit this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: `list.sort` runs in place and returns `None` (which means "has no return value"). Your test code reassigns `names` to `None` by assigning the result of `names.sort`, which is why it breaks. I removed the `names = ` from `names = names.sort(key=lambda l: grp(l))` (and simplified to `names.sort(key=grp)`; no `lambda` wrapper needed since `grp` already has the correct prototype) and [it works fine](http://rextester.com/IQNKL87746).

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""
```

and then do something like

```
 sorted(names, key=lambda x: int(find_between(x, 'Test-', '.model')))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `key` parameter along with `sorted()` to accomplish this, assuming each string is formatted the same way:

```
def get_number_sorted(somelist):
    return sorted(somelist, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0].split('-')[1]))
```

It looks like you might want your list reverse sorted (?), in which case you can add `reverse=True` as such:

```
def get_number_sorted(somelist):
    return sorted(somelist, key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0].split('-')[1]), reverse=True)
number_sorted = get_number_sorted(names)
print(number_sorted)
['Test-20.model', 'Test-10.model', 'Test-8.model', 'Test-6.model', 'Test-4.model', 'Test-1.model']
```

See related: [Key Functions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions)