# Sort a list of strings that contain numbers with SI prefixes

Tags: python, string, sorting, numbers, natural-sort

I am trying to sort the following list:

```
['default.smt',
 'Setup 19k Hz.smt',
 'Setup 1k Hz.smt',
 'Setup 3 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 500 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 55 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 5k Hz.smt',
 'Setup 9k Hz.smt']
```

Where `k` is 1000, so for example `9k` is 9000, and should appear before `19k` which is 19000.

So I need my list to look like this:

```
['default.smt',
 'Setup 3 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 55 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 500 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 1k Hz.smt',
 'Setup 5k Hz.smt',
 'Setup 9k Hz.smt',
 'Setup 19k Hz.smt']
```

The `'default.smt'` cell can either be first or last, I don't mind about that.

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413706/sort-string-list-by-a-number-in-string/48413734#48413734

Comment: For a quick hack for this case only you can use something like `sorted(input, key=lambda x:('k' in x, len(x), x))`, but for something more robust you'd have to write a more advanced key function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex inside a custom key function. In the example I used a naive regex that will fail in some edge-cases, but you can adapt it.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(\d+)(k)?')

li = ['default.smt',
 'Setup 19k Hz.smt',
 'Setup 1k Hz.smt',
 'Setup 3 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 500 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 55 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 5k Hz.smt',
 'Setup 9k Hz.smt']

def magic(e):
    match = regex.findall(e)
    if not match:
        return -1
    num, k = int(match[0][0]), match[0][1]
    if k:
        return num * 1000
    return num

print(sorted(li, key=magic))
```

Outputs

```
['default.smt',
 'Setup 3 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 55 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 500 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 1k Hz.smt',
 'Setup 5k Hz.smt',
 'Setup 9k Hz.smt',
 'Setup 19k Hz.smt']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you think of an example of a edge-case that it may fail?

Comment: @Alon123 If, for example, a string will contain another digit which should not affect the ordering

Answer (score 0):

This answer is basically copy/pasted from [the examples section of `natsort`'s documentation](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples.html#accounting-for-units-when-sorting). All I have done is change the specifics.

```py
>>> import re
>>> import natsort
>>>
>>> # Define how each unit will be transformed
>>> conversion_mapping = {
...         "k": 1000,     # kilo
...         "M": 1000000,  # mega
...         # Extend suffixes as you need
... }
>>>
>>> # This regular expression searches for numbers and units
>>> all_units = "|".join(conversion_mapping.keys())
>>> float_re = natsort.numeric_regex_chooser(natsort.FLOAT | natsort.SIGNED)
>>> unit_finder = re.compile(r"({})({})".format(float_re, all_units), re.IGNORECASE)
>>>
>>> def unit_replacer(matchobj):
...     """
...     Given a regex match object, return a replacement string where units are modified
...     """
...     number = matchobj.group(1)
...     unit = matchobj.group(2)
...     new_number = float(number) * conversion_mapping[unit]
...     return "{}".format(new_number)
...
>>> # Demo time!
>>> data = ['default.smt',
...  'Setup 19k Hz.smt',
...  'Setup 1k Hz.smt',
...  'Setup 3 Hz.smt',
...  'Setup 500 Hz.smt',
...  'Setup 55 Hz.smt',
...  'Setup 5k Hz.smt',
...  'Setup 9k Hz.smt']
>>> [unit_finder.sub(unit_replacer, x) for x in data]
['default.smt',
 'Setup 19000.0 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 1000.0 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 3 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 500 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 55 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 5000.0 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 9000.0 Hz.smt']
>>>
>>> natsort.natsorted(data, key=lambda x: unit_finder.sub(unit_replacer, x), alg=natsort.LOWERCASEFIRST)
['default.smt',
 'Setup 3 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 55 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 500 Hz.smt',
 'Setup 1k Hz.smt',
 'Setup 5k Hz.smt',
 'Setup 9k Hz.smt',
 'Setup 19k Hz.smt']
```

The advantage here is that not only does this use `natsort`'s robust algorithm, but you also get to use `natsort`'s regular expression definition of floats, which [is very thorough](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort/blob/3b9cd60099774ef18b3e5e67877ae81bd5df7e21/natsort/utils.py#L55).

Full disclosure, I am the natsort author.

Answer (score -2):

I did it with the `replace()` function. You can make this code without import. Here is my code:

```
    def sortList(list):

    sortedList = []
    finalList = []
    for elements in list:
        if elements == "default.smt":
            finalList.append(elements)
        else:
            elements = elements.replace("Setup ", "")
            elements = elements.replace("k", "000")
            elements = elements.replace("Hz.smt", "")
            sortedList.append(int(elements))
    sortedList.sort()
    for elements in sortedList:
        elements = str(elements).replace("000", "k")
        finalList.append("Setup " + str(elements) + " Hz.smt")
    return finalList


list = ['default.smt',
        'Setup 19k Hz.smt',
        'Setup 1k Hz.smt',
        'Setup 3 Hz.smt',
        'Setup 500 Hz.smt',
        'Setup 55 Hz.smt',
        'Setup 5k Hz.smt',
        'Setup 9k Hz.smt']
print(sortList(list))
```

The output is the following:

```
['default.smt', 'Setup 3 Hz.smt', 'Setup 55 Hz.smt', 'Setup 500 Hz.smt', 'Setup 1k Hz.smt', 'Setup 5k Hz.smt', 'Setup 9k Hz.smt', 'Setup 19k Hz.smt']
```