# How to make python's read_csv read files in alpha-numerical order

Tags: python, pandas

I made a code that reads a series of CSV files within a folder. It reads all of the CSV files within a folder that I select. The CSV files are formatted like:

A1.CSV, A2.CSV, A3.CSV, ...., A10.CSV, A11.CSV, ..... A24.CSV, B1.CSV, B2.CSV, ...

and so forth.

The code reads the files and then appends them column-wise. However, when it reads the files, the order becomes: A1 > A10 > A11 > ... > A19 > A2 > A20 > A21 ...

Is there a way to make python read the files in alpha-numerical order like:
A1 > A2 > A3 > ... > A10 > A11 >...

I can manually add zeroes to single digits (like A01), which is tedious as I have many files with single digits after an alphabet.

```
for files in os.listdir(full_path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(full_path, files)):
        df = pd.read_excel(files, 'Sheet1')[pkitems]
        df[''] = np.nan
        dfs.append(df)
data = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Comment: This seems to address your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813061/non-alphanumeric-list-order-from-os-listdir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use built-in `list.sort` with two keys:

```
file_list = [file for file in os.listdir(full_path) if file.endswith('.csv')]
file_list.sort(key=lambda x:(os.path.splitext(x)[0][0], int(os.path.splitext(x)[0][1:])))
print(file_list)
['A1.csv',
 'A2.csv',
 ...
 'A23.csv',
 'A24.csv',
 'B1.csv',
 'B2.csv',
 ...
 'B23.csv',
 'B24.csv']
```

Edit: In order to only read the files that end with '.csv'

Comment: I tried using sort but it gave me this error:  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'k list' when I print(file_list).  Is it because the integers after a character may not be integers?

Comment: @BongKyoSeo I think there are files in your `full_path` that do not comply the format of `A0.csv` (i.e. one letter, some digits, and .csv).

Comment: Well, I do have some files with A00.csv. But double digits should be okay with [1:] part if I remember correctly.  Alphabets may run from A to P. Integers run from 1 ~ 24. Besides these files, there are no other files within the folder that I select as full_path.

Comment: @BongKyoSeo From the error message, `os.listdir` returned a file name that contains `k list`. Can you double check? I've also editted my answer to read files that end with '.csv' only.

Comment: oh I just realized that my code creates a folder with name pk list.  I guess the error message printed k list from 'pk list'.

Comment: I should have realized to use if file.endswith as you suggested. Now it works! thanks!

Comment: @BongKyoSeo Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your list of files as built by `os.listdir` in the right order by ordering on the index number if you strip them of the 'A's and convert them to ints:

```
for files in os.listdir(full_path).sort(key=lambda f: int(f[1:])):
    ...
```

This assumes that all your file names start with a single character that can be ignored for the indes

Comment: This fails with many issues: `list.sort()` returns `None`. You are therefore iterating over `None`, which will raise `TypeError`. Furthermore, OP's files contain extensions which is not taken care here. Lastly, `sort` with one key will return `A1, B1, ...`, which is again not a desired output of OP's question