# os.walk different folder ordering on Mac and Linux?

Tags: python, linux, macos, python-3.5, os.walk

Given the following file structure,

```
├── 0=ocfl_object_1.0
├── inventory.json
├── inventory.json.md5
├── v1
│   ├── content
│   │   ├── foo.xml
│   │   └── level1
│   │       └── level2
│   │           └── bar.txt
│   ├── inventory.json
│   └── inventory.json.md5
└── v2
    ├── content
    │   └── duck.txt
    ├── inventory.json
    └── inventory.json.md5
```

I'm wondering if it's possible that python's `os.walk` function returns the folders in different orders on Mac and Linux?  Both are using python 3.5.

Mac:

```
In [15]: for root,folders,files in os.walk('foo/bar'): 
    ...:     print(folders,files) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
['v1', 'v2'] ['inventory.json', '0=ocfl_object_1.0', 'inventory.json.md5']
['content'] ['inventory.json', 'inventory.json.md5']
['level1'] ['foo.xml']
['level2'] []
[] ['bar.txt']
['content'] ['inventory.json', 'inventory.json.md5']
[] ['duck.txt']
```

On Linux:

```
In [54]: for root,folders,files in os.walk('foo/bar'): 
    ...:     print(folders,files) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
['v2', 'v1'] ['inventory.json.md5', 'inventory.json', '0=ocfl_object_1.0']
['content'] ['inventory.json.md5', 'inventory.json']
[] ['duck.txt']
['content'] ['inventory.json.md5', 'inventory.json']
['level1'] ['foo.xml']
['level2'] []
[] ['bar.txt']
```

In the case of Mac, looks as though the folder `v1` is encountered first, while on Linux it's `v2`.  Any insight as to why this might be the case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-alphanumeric list order from os.listdir()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813061/non-alphanumeric-list-order-from-os-listdir)

Comment: The order depends on what the OS returns, which is arbitrary, even using the same OS on different computers. If you want them in a certain order, it's up to you to do the sorting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [documentation on `os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), relevant part:

> *Changed in version 3.5:* This function now calls `os.scandir()` instead
>   of `os.listdir()`, making it faster by reducing the number of calls to
>   `os.stat()`.

And then in [`os.scandir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir):

> Return an iterator of `os.DirEntry` objects corresponding to the entries
>   in the directory given by path. **The entries are yielded in arbitrary
>   order**, and the special entries `'.'` and `'..'` are not included.

Regardless of `listdir()` or `scandir()`, both are returned in arbitrary order anyhow.

In short - order is not to be expected.

---

Having said that, you should be able to manipulate the `dirnames` in the loop based on this part:

> When *topdown* is `True`, the caller can modify the *dirnames* list **in-place**
>   (perhaps using `del` or `slice` assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse
>   into the subdirectories whose names remain in *dirnames*; this can be
>   used to prune the search, **impose a specific order of visiting**, or even
>   to inform `walk()` about directories the caller creates or renames
>   before it resumes `walk()` again. Modifying *dirnames* when *topdown* is
>   `False` has no effect on the behavior of the walk, because in bottom-up
>   mode the directories in *dirnames* are generated before *dirpath* itself
>   is generated.

So if you `folders.sort()` it should work based on your `sorted` order.  I just tried it and it works.  I've also bolded the key part **in-place** - the `folders` must be sorted in place for `os.walk()` to take the order:

```
for root,folders,files in os.walk('foo/bar'): 
    folders.sort()   # <--- sort your folders to impose the order. 
    print(folders,files)
```

Comment: The additional info with `topdown` is really useful. I've used `os.walk` many times and never have read that, so `topdown` used to be relatively meaningless to me. I must have been lucky when modifying the `dirs` variable.

Comment: Actually just learned this while answer this question as well.  I always knew it was in arbitrary order but didn't know you could manipulate the order in place to impose the order.  Guess OP got their wishes :)

Comment: Thanks @Idlehands, this not only answers my question, but some helpful commentary on sorting in place.