# What method does os.listdir() use to obtain a list of files in a directory?

Tags: python, list, arraylist, directory, filenames

I am working on a project where I have to edit a few lines of content in some 400 different files. They are all in the same folder, and have each got unique names. For the sake of this question, I will call them `fileName001.conf` to `fileName420.conf`.

I am using a python script to obtain the contents of each file before going on to make the edits programmatically. At the moment, I am using this snippet to get the files with some `print()` lines for debugging:

```py
folderPath = '/file/path/to/list/of/conf/files'

for filename in os.listdir(folderPath):
  print('filename = ' + filename)
  print('filepath = ' + folderPath + '/' + filename)

  with open(folderPath + '/' + filename, 'r') as currFile:
    #... code goes on...
```

Lines 4 and 5 are designed for debugging only. Running this, I noticed that the script was exhibiting some strange behaviour - the order in which the file names are printed seemed to change on each run. I took this a step further  and added the line:

```py
print(os.listdir(folderPath))
```

Before the for loop in my first code snippet. Now when I run the script from terminal, I can confirm that the output that I get, while contains all file names, ***has a different order each time:***

```bash
RafaGuillermo@virtualMachine:~$ python renamefiles.py
['fileName052.txt', 'fileName216.txt', 'fileName084.txt', 'fileName212.txt', 'fileName380.txt', 'fileName026.txt', 'fileName119.txt', etc...]

RafaGuillermo@virtualMachine:~$ python renamefiles.py
['fileName024.txt', 'fileName004.txt', 'fileName209.txt', 'fileName049.txt', 'fileName166.txt', 'fileName198.txt', 'fileName411.txt', etc...]

RafaGuillermo@virtualMachine:~$
```

As far as getting past this goes - as I want to make sure that I go through the files in the same order each time, I can use

```py
list = sorted(os.listdir(folderPath))
```

Which alphebetises the list, though it seems counter-intuitive that `os.listdir()` returns the list of filenames in a different order each time I run the script.

My question is therefore *not* how can I get a sorted list of files in a directory using `os.listdir()`, but:

***What method does `os.listdir()` use to retrieve a list of files and why does it seemingly populate its return value in a different way on each call?***

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813061/non-alphanumeric-list-order-from-os-listdir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-alphanumeric list order from os.listdir()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813061/non-alphanumeric-list-order-from-os-listdir)

Comment: `sorted(os.listdir())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*This is intended behaviour for the `os.listdir()` method.*

#### More Information:

According to the [Python Software Foundation Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir):

> `os.listdir(path='.')`
>
> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path. ***The list is in arbitrary order, and does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.***

`os.listdir()` is an implementation of a C module which is located in [posixmodule.c of the Python source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/posixmodule.c). The return is based on the structure of the filesystem that the files are stored on and has different implementation depending on the evaluation of a conditional statement determining the local operating system. The directory in which you are calling in `os.listdir()` is opened with the following C code:

```c
static PyObject *
_posix_listdir(path_t *path, PyObject *list) {
    /* stuff */
    dirp = opendir(name);
```

Which opens a stream for the directory name stored in `name`, and returns a pointer to the directory stream with a position of the first directory entry.

Continuing on:

```c
for (;;) {
    errno = 0;
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    ep = readdir(dirp);
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
    if (ep == NULL) {
        if (errno == 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            Py_DECREF(list);
            list = path_error(path);
            goto exit;
        }
    }
    if (ep->d_name[0] == '.' &&
        (NAMLEN(ep) == 1 ||
         (ep->d_name[1] == '.' && NAMLEN(ep) == 2)))
        continue;
    if (return_str)
        v = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefaultAndSize(ep->d_name, NAMLEN(ep));
    else
        v = PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(ep->d_name, NAMLEN(ep));
    if (v == NULL) {
        Py_CLEAR(list);
        break;
    }
    if (PyList_Append(list, v) != 0) {
        Py_DECREF(v);
        Py_CLEAR(list);
        break;
    }
    Py_DECREF(v);
}
```

`readdir()` is called, with the previously assigned pointer to the directory filestream passed as a function parameter. [`readdir()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) on Linux returns a [dirent structure](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/dirent.h.html) which represents the next point in the directory stream that `dirp` is pointing to.

As documented on the `readdir()` Linux man page:

> A directory stream is opened using opendir(3). The order in which filenames are read by successive calls to readdir() depends on the filesystem implementation; it is unlikely that the names will be sorted in any fashion.

So this behaviour is expected and a result of filesystem implementation.

#### References:

- [Miscellaneous operating system interfaces - `os.listdir(path='')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)
- [`cpython / Modules / posixmodule.c` on Github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/posixmodule.c)
- [Linux Programmer's Manual - `readdir()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html)
- [Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6 - `dirent.h` format](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/dirent.h.html)

Comment: [Here is the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c4cacc8c5eab50db8da3140353596f38a01115ca/Modules/posixmodule.c#L3537) for the corresponding  windows implementation.