# Sorting strings by multiple substrings in Python

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.8, natural-sort

I have a list of filenames in the following format `<number>-<number>`

Example below:

```
0-0
1-0
1-1
1-2
1-3

...

31-0
31-1
31-2
```

I want to read them as a sorted list. When I do `sort()` on the `listdir()` output, 10-x is coming right after the `1-x` series.

When I do `.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('-')[0]))`, I get the first number sorted, but the second one(the one after the hyphen are not sorted). Example: `["21-3", "21-0", "21-2", "21-1"]`

So, how do I make sure that I can read my files with the filenames sorted according to the number before the hyphen in the filename *and* also sorted according to the second number in the filename(the one after the hyphen) ?

Desired output:

`["0-0", "1-0", "1-1", "1-2", ...  "31-0", "31-1", "31-2", "31-3"]`

Comment: Do any of these answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545532/python-analog-of-phps-natsort-function-sort-a-list-using-a-natural-order-alg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813061/non-alphanumeric-list-order-from-os-listdir/48030307#48030307 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518/natural-sorting-algorithm

Comment: Your own solution `.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('-')[0]))` is almost correct; you can fix it like this: `.sort(key=lambda x: [int(n) for n in x.split('-')])`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Stef. Split and sort makes sense :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
items = ["31-1", "31-0", "0-0", "0-2", "0-1"]

print(sorted(items, key=lambda s: tuple(map(int, s.split("-")))))
```

Output:

```
['0-0', '0-1', '0-2', '31-0', '31-1']
>>>
```

Comment: Ironically enough, `sorted(items)` gives the wanted result for your particular example of `items = ["31-1", "31-0", "0-0", "0-2", "0-1"]`.